# How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

How do i declare a 2d array using new?

Like, for a "normal" array I would:

```
int* ary = new int[Size]
```

but

```
int** ary = new int[sizeY][sizeX]
```

a) doesn't work/compile and b) doesn't accomplish what:

```
int ary[sizeY][sizeX]
```

does.

Comment: It only works if sizeX is constant: int(*ary)[sizeX] = new int[sizeY][sizeX]; Which is the right way to create a int[sizeY][sizeX] and where all the memory is contiguous. (I don't think this is worth an answer, since probably your sizeX is not constant

Comment: I can't belive all the dozen of answers below are **all** wrong and doesn't answer the question, and yet they are all upvoted. *The above comment by Johanes Shaub is the only correct answer to the question*. A 2D array and an array of pointer to array are two completely separate things, that apparently everyone mixes up.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: That's not 100% correct.  Certainly it does work in that case, but there's a method to make it work where all dimensions vary, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29375830/103167

Answer (score 881, accepted):

If your row length is a compile time constant, C++11 allows

```
auto arr2d = new int [nrows][CONSTANT];
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new/16239446#16239446).  Compilers like gcc that allow variable-length arrays as an extension to C++ can use `new` [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837664/224132) to get fully runtime-variable array dimension functionality like C99 allows, but portable ISO C++ is limited to only the first dimension being variable.

Another efficient option is to do the 2d indexing manually into a big 1d array, as [another answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new/28841507#28841507), allowing the same compiler optimizations as a real 2D array (e.g. proving or checking that arrays don't alias each other / overlap).

---

Otherwise, you can use an array of *pointers to arrays* to allow 2D syntax like contiguous 2D arrays, even though it's not an efficient single large allocation. You can initialize it using a loop, like this:

```
int** a = new int*[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    a[i] = new int[colCount];
```

The above, for `colCount= 5` and `rowCount = 4`, would produce the following:

[image]

Don't forget to `delete` each row separately with a loop, before deleting the array of pointers.  Example in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936709/224132).

Comment: Remember that anything allocated with `new` is created on the heap and must be de-allocated with `delete`, just keep this in mind and be sure to delete this memory from the heap when you're done with it to prevent leaks.

Comment: Also note that this one is an array of pointers. not of arrays. The pointer in turn point to arrays. Important to really correct on the terms, since many tutorials get it wrong too. An array of arrays would be contiguous, which this one is not

Comment: @litb: Is a[][] considered an "array of arrays" in spec or a multidimensional array?

Comment: Yes, a T[][N] would be called "array of array [N] of T" and be an incomplete type, while T[][] would be an invalid type (all except the last dimensions must have a known size). T[N][M] is "array [N] of array[M] of T", while yours, T[sizeX] is "array [sizeX] of T" where T is a pointer to an int. Creating a dynamically 2d array works like this: new int[X][Y]. It will create an array of an allocated-type int[X][Y]. This is a "hole" in C++'s type system, since the ordinary type system of C++ doesn't have array dimensions with sizes not known at compile time, thus these are called "allocated types"

Comment: More to the point, "array of arrays" and "multidimensional array" is one and the same thing.

Comment: I've changed my mind on the type-system question though. I think "allocated type" doesn't mean to denote a completely different type category. I think it just says it's the type used for allocation. So, an array type can have a size not known at compile time, but you cannot declare an array with that type - instead you have to use `new`.

Comment: It is throwing bad_alloc. Why ?

Comment: I like to think of this in a pivoted sense, with a[0] and etc. from left to right on the columns. This way, you can access a[x][y] and have it correctly get the (x, y) coordinate from your array if (0,0) is the top left element of the 2d array. This is the train of thought in graphics programming but there are other ways to think about it depending on the application.

Comment: Can someone explain why we are doing a pre-increment instead of a post-increment?

Comment: This is super wrong. First it's not a two-dimensional array, second the arrays can't be deallocated in case of exception.

Comment: Plus 1 if you can deallocate the memory allotted by new using the delete operator.

Comment: Oh my God, this is complete garbage, this is utterly wrong. This is no 2D array. "A dynamic 2D array is basically an array of pointers to arrays." – **NOOOO,** FFS! `T (*ptr)[M] = new T[N][M];` is the correct solution… No amount of arrays-of-pointers will ever be the same as an array-of-arrays…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You can argue it is not a 2D array.  It's true.  It can be indexed like a 2D array, but it is not a 2D array.  The memory layout is in fact portrayed in the picture. The problem with that statement is it fails to work if M is not constant.

Comment: So... the array WITHIN the array has to be of a constant size?? Well that's not very dynamic is it? Inside that for loop, can't I have colCount to be different values at each iteration??

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari how will this work if we want to declare a global 2D array?

Comment: @Kekoa Also, keep in mind `delete[]` function, that deletes arrays.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari "It can be indexed like a 2D array" - **No**. It uses the same syntax, but the semantics are very different. You will see the difference if you ever have to use large matrices (aka 2D arrays) on memory-constraint systems or can't use dynamic allocation at all. Or if you have performance issues, i.e. have to optimise datastructures for cache and DRAM access. In addition this is much more complicated and clumsy than using a 2D array.

Comment: What about `int(*a)[rowSize] = (int(*)[rowSize]) new int[rowSize*colSize];`, which accepts both dimensions being variable. Memory addresses are contiguous, only 1 thing to free, and you just cast it to a 2d array pointer with the proper rowSize. With that cast the compiler apparently knows how to set up the correct indexing arithmetic.

Comment: @theferrit32 `int(*)[rowSize]` requires `rowSize` be constexpr. What does work is `int** a = new int*[rowCount]; int* b = new int[rowCount * colCount]; for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i, b += colCount) { a[i] = b; }` To cleanup you `delete[] *a; delete[]a;`

Comment: better to use vector of vector

Comment: If I want to pass arrays declared as `T (*ptr)[M] = new T[N][M];` to functions (M and N can be different) by reference, how do I do so?

Comment: This should definitely not be the accepted answer! It leads novice programmers in a totally different direction and it contains false statements. Probably the questioner was also mislead and therefore accepted it. I strongly suggest mods to clean this up!

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari: I made an edit to mention the other better (more efficient) ways of handling 2D arrays.  It's fairly intrusive so you might want to adjust or roll it back. 
 IMO the top answer on this FAQ question shouldn't only mention the worst way to do 2D arrays.  It seems like more than half the C++ SIMD optimization questions about matrices include code like that, making arrays of pointers masquerading as 2D arrays, despite that being well known as a bad choice for high-performance code.  I know there are other answers on this same question, but this should at least mention/link them.

Comment: What I usually do is allocate contiguous memory in one go: int** a = new int*[rowCount]; int* m= new int[rowCount * colCount]; for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) a[i] = m+i * colCount;

Comment: is it possible to use a placement pointer with that new? i.e. `new (buf) int [nrows][CONSTANT];` My g++ says "no matching function call..." I'm trying to declare an array for the compiler in a chunk of hugepages-backed memory.

Answer (score 352):

```
int** ary = new int[sizeY][sizeX]
```

should be:

```
int **ary = new int*[sizeY];
for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i) {
    ary[i] = new int[sizeX];
}
```

and then clean up would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i) {
    delete [] ary[i];
}
delete [] ary;
```

**EDIT:** as Dietrich Epp pointed out in the comments this is not exactly a light weight solution. An alternative approach would be to use one large block of memory:

```
int *ary = new int[sizeX*sizeY];

// ary[i][j] is then rewritten as
ary[i*sizeY+j]
```

Comment: It's a little heavier weight than it needs to be, and it allocates more blocks than you need.  Multidimensional arrays only need one block of memory, they don't need one block per row.  Allocating only one block makes cleanup simpler too.

Comment: @Kevin: Allocating just a single contiguous block is the way to go (less impact on allocator, better locality, etc).  But you don't have to sacrifice clean subscripting.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29375830/103167

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i*sizeX+j`? If I recall correctly, with row major ordering it should be row*numColumns+col.

Comment: hm, nice thinking, indeed it's only a matter of representation - the rest is perspective. clever

Comment: @DietrichEpp Is the reading from an array faster if we allocate one block only?

Comment: @Borna: In general using a single 2D array is going to be faster than an array of arrays. Following two pointers can cause pipeline stalls. As always, it depends on access patterns.

Comment: Yes, it should be i * sizeX + j. I was having a hard time debugging my program until I saw the comment here.

Comment: For future readers being confused about the indexing, i.e. whether it should be ```i*sizeX+j``` or ```i*sizeY+j```. Well it depends on how you see the matrix. I hope this makes it clearer: ```int * ary = new int[nRows*nColumns]``` and indexing via ```ary[iRow*nColumns + iColumns]```

Comment: @KevinLoney What I usually do is allocate contiguous memory in one go: int** a = new int*[rowCount]; int* m= new int[rowCount * colCount]; for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) a[i] = m+i * colCount;

Comment: @BenVoigt , please take a look at my comment just above: you get contiguous memory, new and delete it in one statement, and get both stiles of referencing:
a[i][j] is ok and m[i*colCount+j] also ok.

Comment: @Kphysics: I've recommended that exact approach myself several times.  Except don't use `new`, use `make_unique<T*[]>` and `make_unique<T[]>`

Comment: @Kphysics: for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/29375830/103167

Answer (score 252):

Although [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/358475) will give you your desired indexing syntax, it is doubly inefficient: big and slow both in space and time. There's a better way.

**Why That Answer is Big and Slow**

The proposed solution is to create a dynamic array of pointers, then initializing each pointer to its own, independent dynamic array. The **advantage** of this approach is that it gives you the indexing syntax you're used to, so if you want to find the value of the matrix at position x,y, you say:

```
int val = matrix[ x ][ y ];
```

This works because matrix[x] returns a pointer to an array, which is then indexed with [y]. Breaking it down:

```
int* row = matrix[ x ];
int  val = row[ y ];
```

Convenient, yes? We like our [ x ][ y ] syntax.

But the solution has a big **disadvantage**, which is that it is both fat and slow.

Why?

The reason that it's both fat and slow is actually the same. Each "row" in the matrix is a separately allocated dynamic array. Making a heap allocation is expensive both in time and space. The allocator takes time to make the allocation, sometimes running O(n) algorithms to do it. And the allocator "pads" each of your row arrays with extra bytes for bookkeeping and alignment. That extra space costs...well...extra space. The deallocator will *also* take extra time when you go to deallocate the matrix, painstakingly free-ing up each individual row allocation. Gets me in a sweat just thinking about it.

There's another reason it's slow. These separate allocations tend to live in discontinuous parts of memory. One row may be at address 1,000, another at address 100,000—you get the idea. This means that when you're traversing the matrix, you're leaping through memory like a wild person. This tends to result in cache misses that vastly slow down your processing time.

So, if you absolute must have your cute [x][y] indexing syntax, use that solution. If you want quickness and smallness (and if you don't care about those, why are you working in C++?), you need a different solution.

**A Different Solution**

The better solution is to allocate your whole matrix as a single dynamic array, then use (slightly) clever indexing math of your own to access cells. The indexing math is only very slightly clever; nah, it's not clever at all: it's obvious.

```
class Matrix
{
    ...
    size_t index( int x, int y ) const { return x + m_width * y; }
};
```

Given this `index()` function (which I'm imagining is a member of a class because it needs to know the `m_width` of your matrix), you can access cells within your matrix array. The matrix array is allocated like this:

```
array = new int[ width * height ];
```

So the equivalent of this in the slow, fat solution:

```
array[ x ][ y ]
```

...is this in the quick, small solution:

```
array[ index( x, y )]
```

Sad, I know. But you'll get used to it. And your CPU will thank you.

Comment: I don't quite get this. So `array` is something raw, not of the `Matrix` type? Then, how does `m_width` work here? And shouldn't it be `static`? Also, if we're wrapping arrays *anyway*, why not implement an `.at(j, i)` member function instead? Great answer otherwise (especially the 'don't ptr to ptr please' bit; been having trouble with that in assignments so I agree).

Comment: @Noein, I sort of sketched a solution without prescribing a particular one. More detail might look like: `class Matrix { int* array; int m_width; public: Matrix( int w, int h ) : m_width( w ), array( new int[ w * h ] ) {} ~Matrix() { delete[] array; } int at( int x, int y ) const { return array[ index( x, y ) ]; } protected: int index( int x, int y ) const { return x + m_width * y; } };` If you straighten out that code it might make sense, and might shed light on the answer above.

Comment: I like this solution a lot, is it applicable to 3 dimensions array too ? I'm thinking something like this : (x + m_width * y) + (m_width * m_height * z)

Comment: The **major problem with this solution** is that there is **extra computation** for every index.

It **becomes worse if you put the index calculation in a function** which adds extra overhead.

At least, consider using **macros** or **inline functions** to reduce overhead. An example macro for C++:
`#define ROW_COL_TO_INDEX(row, col, num_cols) (row*num_cols + col)`
Then you can use it as
`int COLS = 4; A[ ROW_COL_TO_INDEX(r, c, COLS) ] = 75;`

The overhead really affects when we do matrix multiplications which are of complexity **O(n^3)** or **O(n^2.81) for Strassen's algorithm**.

Comment: You can now have lambdas return lvalue references, which can make this a little more user friendly: `auto one_dim_array = new int[num_rows * num_cols]; auto two_dim_array = [num_cols, &one_dim_array](size_t row, size_t col) -> int& { return one_dim_array[row*num_cols + col]; }` and use it like `two_dim_array(i, j) = 5`

Comment: @AshKetchum Inlining (or maybe macro substitution) makes sense to optimize, but how is the compiled computation more complex than what needs to be done to resolve the address of a[x][y] ?

Comment: Anyone who has done some Cuda programming will recognize this as a good solution;

Comment: @Dronz With `a[x][y]`, what you are actually doing is `*(*(a + x) + y)`: two additions and two memory fetches. With `a[index(x, y)]`, what you are actually doing is `*(a + x + w*y)`: two additions, one multiplication, and one memory fetch. The latter is often preferable, for the reasons exposed in this answer (i.e., trading the extra memory fetch with a multiplication is worth it, especially because the data isn't fragmented and therefore you don't cache-miss).

Comment: @BorisDalstein Oh, that's interesting and useful, thanks very much for the explanation!

Comment: You can even keep the `array[x][y]` syntax if you are willing to write a row proxy for `Matrix::operator[]` to return

Answer (score 128):

In C++11 it is possible:

```
auto array = new double[M][N];
```

This way, the memory is not initialized. To initialize it do this instead:

```
auto array = new double[M][N]();
```

Sample program (compile with "g++ -std=c++11"):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const auto M = 2;
    const auto N = 2;

    // allocate (no initializatoin)
    auto array = new double[M][N];

    // pollute the memory
    array[0][0] = 2;
    array[1][0] = 3;
    array[0][1] = 4;
    array[1][1] = 5;

    // re-allocate, probably will fetch the same memory block (not portable)
    delete[] array;
    array = new double[M][N];

    // show that memory is not initialized
    for(int r = 0; r < M; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < N; c++)
            cout << array[r][c] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete[] array;

    // the proper way to zero-initialize the array
    array = new double[M][N]();

    // show the memory is initialized
    for(int r = 0; r < M; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < N; c++)
            cout << array[r][c] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    int info;
    cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(array).name(),0,0,&info) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 4 
3 5 

0 0 
0 0 
double (*) [2]
```

Comment: I need to do this in a class, hence I can't use auto. What would be the proper type for the array?

Comment: Can you use this then:
`using arr2d = double(*)[2];
arr2d array = new double[M][N];`

Comment: +1: this is what the OP asked for. The proper type for this is either `double (*)[M][N]` or `double(*)[][N]` with M, N being constant expressions.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that the dimensions cannot be a run-time value, but should be known at compile-time.

Comment: How to pass twodimensional arrays to funcions in C++ (or C++11)?  In C11 standard it can be done like that fn(int col,int row, int array[col][row]): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004668/c-allocating-a-matrix-in-a-function/27366086#27366086

Comment: @legends2k Only `N` has to be known, `M` can be non-const.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, [indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432831/why-cant-i-omit-the-dimensions-altogether-when-initializing-a-multi-dimensional?lq=1#comment8986525_7433226), however the question was specifically about having both dimensions unknown at compile-time.

Comment: This answer would be better if it didn't make it seem it is only possible to do this since C++11.

Comment: Follow-up question: How should I free the array (created by new[10][10])?

Comment: why cant I do this though? =>  double(*)[2] array = new double[M][N]();

Comment: So does it mean I don't need to `delete` each sub dimension arrays in a loop?

Comment: @MohammadAlaggan Thank you so much for this, I have a follow up question.
using arr2d = int(\*)[5];
arr2d b = new int[3][5];
works but
why doesn't 
int(\*)[5] b = new int[3][5]; does not work

Answer (score 64):

I presume from your static array example that you want a rectangular array, and not a jagged one. You can use the following:

```
int *ary = new int[sizeX * sizeY];
```

Then you can access elements as:

```
ary[y*sizeX + x]
```

Don't forget to use delete[] on `ary`.

Comment: This is a good way to do it.  You can also do vector<int> with size sizeX*sizeY for some nice extra safety.

Comment: The best thing is to wrap this code in a class - you can perform a clean-up in destructor and you can implements methods get(x, y) and set(x,y, val) instead of forcing user to do multiplication by himself. Implementing operator[] is more tricky, but I believe it's possible.

Answer (score 64):

There are three general techniques that I would recommend for this in C++11 and above:

- One for dimensions known at compile-time.
- One for dimensions known at run-time and using < C++23
- One for dimensions known at run-time and using >= C++23

All answers assume you want uniform, two-dimensional arrays (not jagged ones).

#### Compile time dimensions

Use a `std::array` of `std::array` and then use `new` to put it on the heap:

```cpp
// the alias helps cut down on the noise:
using grid = std::array<std::array<int, sizeX>, sizeY>;
grid * ary = new grid;
```

Again, this only works if the sizes of the dimensions are known at compile time.

#### Run-time dimensions (< C++23)

The best way to accomplish a 2 dimensional array with sizes only known at run-time is to wrap it into a class. The class will allocate a 1d array and then overload `operator []` to provide indexing for the first dimension.
This works because in C++ a 2D array is row-major:

[image: matrix shown in logical form and one-dimensional form]

<sup>(Taken from http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/)</sup>

A contiguous sequence of memory is good for performance reasons and is also easy to clean up. Here's an example class that omits a lot of useful methods but shows the basic idea:

```
#include <memory>

class Grid {
  size_t _rows;
  size_t _columns;
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> data;

public:
  Grid(size_t rows, size_t columns)
      : _rows{rows},
        _columns{columns},
        data{std::make_unique<int[]>(rows * columns)} {}

  size_t rows() const { return _rows; }

  size_t columns() const { return _columns; }

  int *operator[](size_t row) { return row * _columns + data.get(); }

  int &operator()(size_t row, size_t column) {
    return data[row * _columns + column];
  }
}
```

So we create an array with `std::make_unique<int[]>(rows * columns)` entries. We overload `operator []` which will index the row for us. It returns an `int *` which points to the beginning of the row, which can then be dereferenced as normal for the column. Note that `make_unique` first ships in C++14 but you can polyfill it in C++11 if necessary.

It's also common for these types of structures to overload `operator()` as well:

```
  int &operator()(size_t row, size_t column) {
    return data[row * _columns + column];
  }
```

<sup>Technically I haven't used `new` here, but it's trivial to move from `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` to `int *` and use `new`/`delete`.</sup>

#### Run-time dimensions (C++23)

For C++23, there is [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan). This view generalizes a contiguous region of memory into a multi-dimension view. For instance, a 1x12 region of memory could be a 4x3 or 2x3x2, and so on, as long as the view actually makes sense on top of the underlying memory region. Here's an [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan#example):

```
#include <mdspan>
#include <print>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

  // View data as contiguous memory representing 2 rows of 6
  // ints each
  auto ms2 = std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 6);
  // View the same data as a 3D array 2 x 3 x 2
  auto ms3 = std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 3, 2);

  // write data using 2D view
  for (size_t i = 0; i != ms2.extent(0); i++)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != ms2.extent(1); j++)
      ms2[i, j] = i * 1000 + j;

  // read back using 3D view
  for (size_t i = 0; i != ms3.extent(0); i++) {
    std::println("slice @ i = {}", i);
    for (size_t j = 0; j != ms3.extent(1); j++) {
      for (size_t k = 0; k != ms3.extent(2); k++)
        std::print("{} ", ms3[i, j, k]);
      std::println("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would it be possible to make the rows and columns template parameters?

Comment: If you know the dimensions at compile time (which you do if you are using template parameters) then I recommend using a `std::array` of `std::array`s: `std::array<std::array<int, columns> rows>`.

Comment: May I say this is a sophisticated/modern answer with underneath philosophy very similar to (simpler, in terms of LOC and concepts) answer given by @kamshi?

Comment: They are fairly comparable with respect to the underlying technique: there is a single array that holds all values in all dimensions. Then, somehow return pointers to the beginning of each row. In practice the class will usually have more useful methods, possibly have copy constructor and copy assignment operators, have `asserts` for debug builds to verify memory accesses, etc. These additions generally make it easier and nicer to work with.

Comment: Also, @KcFnMi, if you decide to use [kamshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672888/538216)'s answer then be sure to read [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new?noredirect=1#comment70741893_27672888)'s comment about using `make_unique` instead of `new/delete`.

Comment: typo: `using grid = std::array<std::array<int, sizeX> sizeY>;` is missing a comma before `sizeY`.

Answer (score 36):

Why not use STL:vector? So easy, and you don't need to delete the vector.

```
int rows = 100;
int cols = 200;
vector< vector<int> > f(rows, vector<int>(cols));
f[rows - 1][cols - 1] = 0; // use it like arrays
```

You can also initialise the 'arrays', just give it a default value

```
const int DEFAULT = 1234;
vector< vector<int> > f(rows, vector<int>(cols, DEFAULT));
```

Source: [How to Create 2, 3 (or Multi) Dimensional Arrays in C/C++?](https://helloacm.com/how-to-create-2-3-or-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c-c/)

Comment: This is not a good solution if I don't want to load STL because of memory constrains.

Comment: @katta most nontrivial C++ programs do use STL anyway, so this is a good solution, just not for some minor number of cases including yours.

Comment: What I don't understand is why so many people think of the first index as the rows, and the second as the columns. Rebellion against XY coordinate diagrams in math class?

Comment: @Dronz It's because that's the C++ memory model -- the columns are contiguous in memory, not the rows. In Fortran it's the other way.

Comment: @LeviMorrison Oh! That actually makes intuitive sense to me in this case, thanks! (I was thinking it was related to how many modern graphics coordinates use X and Y.)

Comment: Also you do not need to have spaces between >s.

Comment: One downside: The memory used is not one contiguous block. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898007/stdvector-of-stdvectors-contiguity) So some low-level operations might be a bit more complex, like writing to a file or stream, or setting all the memory cells to a particular value.

Answer (score 33):

This question was bugging me - it's a common enough problem that a good solution should already exist, something better than the vector of vectors or rolling your own array indexing.

When something ought to exist in C++ but doesn't, the first place to look is [boost.org](http://www.boost.org/). There I found the [Boost Multidimensional Array Library, **`multi_array`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html). It even includes a `multi_array_ref` class that can be used to wrap your own one-dimensional array buffer.

Comment: I understand your argument, i personally don't understand why it has to be so difficult, honestly this is the reason why we lose so many programmers to Java, there it just works out of the box! These are base features which make c++ guys lose time!

Comment: I might just add, i find this the best solution but i guess for some people it needs a lot of brain to understand all the steps, especially for beginners... ;)! I see 80% of C++ programmers fail when they see typedef'ed stuff.

Comment: @OliverStutz that's the danger of being first. The most recent C++ standards have been trying desperately to make things less burdensome, my favorite is the `auto` keyword. I'm surprised they haven't tried to tackle 2D arrays, especially since Boost has already shown the way.

Comment: it's funny how the whole development automation was slept in. Now the only easy out of the box advantage is java. I would really like c++ to take a leap, it has been a mighty and powerful language since ever... why having a lightsaber if you don't use it!

Comment: What's bugging me even more is how far C++ is behind C in this: C99 allows for real multidimensional arrays allocated on the heap with dimensions defined at run time, and C++17 still does not come close to what C99 allows...

Comment: re: cmaster's point about C99: [Malloc a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36890624) / [Freaky way of allocating two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36799070).  That depends on VLA support, and if you have that as a C++ extension, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837664/224132) shows that there's an equivalent with `new` instead of `new[]` - apparently `new[]` not supporting variable dimensions was the problem).  Note that `new int [var][CONST]` does already work in ISO C++.

Comment: Here I found the sentences that I needed to know - " C99 allows for real multidimensional arrays allocated on the heap with dimensions defined at run time, and C++17 still does not come close to what C99 allows"... I was using C99 and now new to C++ and was wondering dynamic allocation of 2D array in C++ is why this controversial... it seems that it is kind of a nature of C++

Comment: @SangjunLee sometimes C++ compilers that are also C compilers will provide C features to C++ as an extension.  Unfortunately using those extensions makes your code non-portable and gets you yelled at on S.O.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I am trying to parallelize my C program via CUDA. I have searched for a while (like a week), but there seems to no way to activate C99 feature by the nvcc compiler. The thing is, the multi-dimensional array only appears in the I/O part of my code, therefore in fact GPU never will use multi-dimensional array. But still, I was unable to compile my code via nvcc, and as these multi-dimensional arrays are not critical to the code performance and mainly for the cosmetics in the way of delaring arrays (I think double pointers are ugly), I ended up just flattening those into 1D array.

Answer (score 19):

**A 2D array is basically a 1D array of pointers, where every pointer is pointing to a 1D array, which will hold the actual data.**

Here N is row and M is column.

**dynamic allocation**

```
int** ary = new int*[N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      ary[i] = new int[M];
```

**fill**

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
      ary[i][j] = i;
```

**print**

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
      std::cout << ary[i][j] << "\n";
```

**free**

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    delete [] ary[i];
delete [] ary;
```

Answer (score 17):

This problem has bothered me for 15 years, and all the solutions supplied weren't satisfactory for me. How do you create a dynamic multidimensional array contiguously in memory? Today I finally found the answer. Using the following code, you can do just that:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "You have to specify the two array dimensions" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int sizeX, sizeY;

    sizeX = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    sizeY = std::stoi(argv[2]);

    if (sizeX <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid dimension x" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if (sizeY <= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid dimension y" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    /******** Create a two dimensional dynamic array in continuous memory ******
     *
     * - Define the pointer holding the array
     * - Allocate memory for the array (linear)
     * - Allocate memory for the pointers inside the array
     * - Assign the pointers inside the array the corresponding addresses
     *   in the linear array
     **************************************************************************/

    // The resulting array
    unsigned int** array2d;

    // Linear memory allocation
    unsigned int* temp = new unsigned int[sizeX * sizeY];

    // These are the important steps:
    // Allocate the pointers inside the array,
    // which will be used to index the linear memory
    array2d = new unsigned int*[sizeY];

    // Let the pointers inside the array point to the correct memory addresses
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i)
    {
        array2d[i] = (temp + i * sizeX);
    }



    // Fill the array with ascending numbers
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
        {
            array2d[y][x] = x + y * sizeX;
        }
    }



    // Code for testing
    // Print the addresses
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
        {
            std::cout << std::hex << &(array2d[y][x]) << ' ';
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Print the array
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; ++y)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << &(array2d[y][0]) << std::dec;
        std::cout << ": ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; ++x)
        {
            std::cout << array2d[y][x] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }



    // Free memory
    delete[] array2d[0];
    delete[] array2d;
    array2d = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

When you invoke the program with the values sizeX=20 and sizeY=15, the output will be the following:

```
0x603010 0x603014 0x603018 0x60301c 0x603020 0x603024 0x603028 0x60302c 0x603030 0x603034 0x603038 0x60303c 0x603040 0x603044 0x603048 0x60304c 0x603050 0x603054 0x603058 0x60305c 0x603060 0x603064 0x603068 0x60306c 0x603070 0x603074 0x603078 0x60307c 0x603080 0x603084 0x603088 0x60308c 0x603090 0x603094 0x603098 0x60309c 0x6030a0 0x6030a4 0x6030a8 0x6030ac 0x6030b0 0x6030b4 0x6030b8 0x6030bc 0x6030c0 0x6030c4 0x6030c8 0x6030cc 0x6030d0 0x6030d4 0x6030d8 0x6030dc 0x6030e0 0x6030e4 0x6030e8 0x6030ec 0x6030f0 0x6030f4 0x6030f8 0x6030fc 0x603100 0x603104 0x603108 0x60310c 0x603110 0x603114 0x603118 0x60311c 0x603120 0x603124 0x603128 0x60312c 0x603130 0x603134 0x603138 0x60313c 0x603140 0x603144 0x603148 0x60314c 0x603150 0x603154 0x603158 0x60315c 0x603160 0x603164 0x603168 0x60316c 0x603170 0x603174 0x603178 0x60317c 0x603180 0x603184 0x603188 0x60318c 0x603190 0x603194 0x603198 0x60319c 0x6031a0 0x6031a4 0x6031a8 0x6031ac 0x6031b0 0x6031b4 0x6031b8 0x6031bc 0x6031c0 0x6031c4 0x6031c8 0x6031cc 0x6031d0 0x6031d4 0x6031d8 0x6031dc 0x6031e0 0x6031e4 0x6031e8 0x6031ec 0x6031f0 0x6031f4 0x6031f8 0x6031fc 0x603200 0x603204 0x603208 0x60320c 0x603210 0x603214 0x603218 0x60321c 0x603220 0x603224 0x603228 0x60322c 0x603230 0x603234 0x603238 0x60323c 0x603240 0x603244 0x603248 0x60324c 0x603250 0x603254 0x603258 0x60325c 0x603260 0x603264 0x603268 0x60326c 0x603270 0x603274 0x603278 0x60327c 0x603280 0x603284 0x603288 0x60328c 0x603290 0x603294 0x603298 0x60329c 0x6032a0 0x6032a4 0x6032a8 0x6032ac 0x6032b0 0x6032b4 0x6032b8 0x6032bc 0x6032c0 0x6032c4 0x6032c8 0x6032cc 0x6032d0 0x6032d4 0x6032d8 0x6032dc 0x6032e0 0x6032e4 0x6032e8 0x6032ec 0x6032f0 0x6032f4 0x6032f8 0x6032fc 0x603300 0x603304 0x603308 0x60330c 0x603310 0x603314 0x603318 0x60331c 0x603320 0x603324 0x603328 0x60332c 0x603330 0x603334 0x603338 0x60333c 0x603340 0x603344 0x603348 0x60334c 0x603350 0x603354 0x603358 0x60335c 0x603360 0x603364 0x603368 0x60336c 0x603370 0x603374 0x603378 0x60337c 0x603380 0x603384 0x603388 0x60338c 0x603390 0x603394 0x603398 0x60339c 0x6033a0 0x6033a4 0x6033a8 0x6033ac 0x6033b0 0x6033b4 0x6033b8 0x6033bc 0x6033c0 0x6033c4 0x6033c8 0x6033cc 0x6033d0 0x6033d4 0x6033d8 0x6033dc 0x6033e0 0x6033e4 0x6033e8 0x6033ec 0x6033f0 0x6033f4 0x6033f8 0x6033fc 0x603400 0x603404 0x603408 0x60340c 0x603410 0x603414 0x603418 0x60341c 0x603420 0x603424 0x603428 0x60342c 0x603430 0x603434 0x603438 0x60343c 0x603440 0x603444 0x603448 0x60344c 0x603450 0x603454 0x603458 0x60345c 0x603460 0x603464 0x603468 0x60346c 0x603470 0x603474 0x603478 0x60347c 0x603480 0x603484 0x603488 0x60348c 0x603490 0x603494 0x603498 0x60349c 0x6034a0 0x6034a4 0x6034a8 0x6034ac 0x6034b0 0x6034b4 0x6034b8 0x6034bc 

0x603010: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
0x603060: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
0x6030b0: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
0x603100: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
0x603150: 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
0x6031a0: 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 
0x6031f0: 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 
0x603240: 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 
0x603290: 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 
0x6032e0: 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 
0x603330: 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 
0x603380: 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 
0x6033d0: 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 
0x603420: 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 
0x603470: 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299
```

As you can see, the multidimensional array lies contiguously in memory, and no two memory addresses are overlapping. Even the routine for freeing the array is simpler than the standard way of dynamically allocating memory for every single column (or row, depending on how you view the array). Since the array basically consists of two linear arrays, only these two have to be (and can be) freed.

This method can be extended for more than two dimensions with the same concept. I won't do it here, but when you get the idea behind it, it is a simple task.

I hope this code will help you as much as it helped me.

Comment: There's still an extra array of pointers.  Code using the array has to do the extra layer of indirection, because it can't assume `array2d[i] = buffer + i * sizeX`.  So this helps to a small degree, but in code using the array, the compiler can't just increment pointers to scan the array.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the way to do it.  But it's the C way to do it, in C++ we'd use `make_unique<int[]>(sizeX*sizeY)` to set up the contiguous storage, and `make_unique<int*[]>(sizeX)` to set up storage for the pointers (which should be assigned the same way you show).  This frees you from the requirement to call `delete[]` twice at the end.

Comment: This answer is kind of making a ton of sense to me, even more considering @BenVoigt comment. The extra array of pointers @PeterCordes refer to, is it `temp`? Considering the benefits (continuos 2d array with unknown dimentions at compile time), I'm not sure I care having it dangling. I didn't understant what @PeterCordes mean by `extra layer of indirection`, what is it? Why the parenthesis, `array2d[i] = (temp + i * sizeX)`;

Comment: delete[] array2d[0] is the same as delete[] temp?

Comment: This is still not a good solution; you are storing many pointers that can be calculated instead, and element access would need two pointer indirections. Use a proper multidimensional array library, such as Boost.ublas, Boost.MultiArray, or https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi (disclaimer, my library).

Answer (score 16):

How to allocate a contiguous multidimensional array in GNU C++?  There's a GNU extension that allows the "standard" syntax to work.

It seems the problem come from operator new []. Make sure you use operator new instead :

```
double (* in)[n][n] = new (double[m][n][n]);  // GNU extension
```

And that's all : you get a C-compatible multidimensional array...

Comment: What compiler are you using?  The array syntax compiles and runs fine with g++ 4.6.4 and 4.7.3.  I'm just getting a warning on the last ] before the = that "value computed is not used" or "statement has no effect".  However, if I use g++ 4.8.1 (supposedly fully c++11 compliant), it throws errors on n and o not being constant "array size in operator new must be constant", and points to the last ] in the line.

Comment: @cmaster `double (*in)[m][n] = (double (*)[m][n])new double[k*m*n];` doesn't work too. I'm getting C2057, C2540 errors on `n` because it isn't known at compile time. I don't understand why I can't do it, because memory allocated properly and it's only _pointers_ to handle this memory conveniently. (VS 2010)

Comment: @user3241228 `gcc` fooled me when I wrote this: supplying `-std=c++11` is not enough to switch on strict standard conformance, `-pedantic-errors` is required as well. Without the later flag, `gcc` happily accepts the cast, even though it is indeed not according to the C++ standard. With what I know now, I can only advise to fall back to C when doing stuff that's heavily reliant on multidimensional arrays. C99 is just much more powerful in this regard than even C++17 will be.

Comment: @cmaster dynamically allocated VLAs are syntactic sugar anyway... they're good in C because there's nothing else, but C++ has better syntactic sugar :)

Comment: @M.M Pity that C++ does not have syntactic sugar for a true, consecutive multidimensional array allocated on the heap with sizes that are only known at runtime. As long as you don't need this, C++ syntactic sugar is fine. But when you need all the above, even FORTRAN beats C++...

Comment: Just for the record, the C equivalent with malloc uses the same syntax to declare the pointer-to-2D-array that holds the result: [Malloc a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36890624)

Answer (score 13):

**typedef is your friend**

After going back and looking at many of the other answers I found that a deeper explanation is in order, as many of the other answers either suffer from performance problems or force you to use unusual or burdensome syntax to declare the array, or access the array elements ( or all the above ).

First off, this answer assumes you know the dimensions of the array at compile time.  If you do, then this is the best solution as it will both give **the best performance** and allows you to use **standard array syntax to access the array elements**.

The reason this gives the best performance is because it allocates all of the arrays as a contiguous block of memory meaning that you are likely to have less page misses and better spacial locality.  Allocating in a loop may cause the individual arrays to end up scattered on multiple non-contiguous pages through the virtual memory space as the allocation loop could be interrupted ( possibly multiple times ) by other threads or processes, or simply due to the discretion of the allocator filling in small, empty memory blocks it happens to have available.

The other benefits are a simple declaration syntax and standard array access syntax.

In C++ using new:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

typedef double (array5k_t)[5000];

array5k_t *array5k = new array5k_t[5000];

array5k[4999][4999] = 10;
printf("array5k[4999][4999] == %f\n", array5k[4999][4999]);

return 0;
}
```

Or C style using calloc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

typedef double (*array5k_t)[5000];

array5k_t array5k = calloc(5000, sizeof(double)*5000);

array5k[4999][4999] = 10;
printf("array5k[4999][4999] == %f\n", array5k[4999][4999]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Accessing beyond the end of an array is not guaranteed to cause an error.  If you're lucky, the program will just crash.  You're definitely in the realm of undefined behavior.

Comment: True, although the purpose of this example is really just to show how to use typedef and new together to declare a 2D array.

Comment: I seriously liked your answer too much. I myself had been an advocator of typedef.

Answer (score 9):

The purpose of this answer is not to add anything new that the others don't already cover, but to extend @Kevin Loney's answer.

You could use the lightweight declaration:

```
int *ary = new int[SizeX*SizeY]
```

and access syntax will be:

```
ary[i*SizeY+j]     // ary[i][j]
```

but this is cumbersome for most, and can lead to confusion. So, you can define a macro as follows:

```
#define ary(i, j)   ary[(i)*SizeY + (j)]
```

Now you can access the array using the very similar syntax `ary(i, j)  // means ary[i][j]`.
This has the advantages of being simple and beautiful, and at the same time, using expressions in place of the indices is also simpler and less confusing.

To access, say, ary[2+5][3+8], you can write `ary(2+5, 3+8)` instead of the complex-looking `ary[(2+5)*SizeY + (3+8)]` i.e. it saves parentheses and helps readability.

**Caveats:**

- Although the syntax is very similar, it is NOT the same.
- In case you pass the array to other functions, `SizeY` has to be passed with the same name (or instead be declared as a global variable).

Or, if you need to use the array in multiple functions, then you could add SizeY also as another parameter in the macro definition like so:

```
#define ary(i, j, SizeY)  ary[(i)*(SizeY)+(j)]
```

You get the idea. Of course, this becomes too long to be useful, but it can still prevent the confusion of + and *.

This is not recommended definitely, and it will be condemned as bad practice by most experienced users, but I couldn't resist sharing it because of its elegance.

**Edit:**
If you want a portable solution that works for any number of arrays, you can use this syntax:

```
#define access(ar, i, j, SizeY) ar[(i)*(SizeY)+(j)]
```

and then you can pass on any array to the call, with any size using the access syntax:

```
access(ary, i, j, SizeY)      // ary[i][j]
```

P.S.: I've tested these, and the same syntax works (as both an lvalue and an rvalue) on g++14 and g++11 compilers.

Answer (score 7):

Try doing this:

```
int **ary = new int* [sizeY];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++)
    ary[i] = new int[sizeX];
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, I have two options. The first one shows the concept of an array of arrays or pointer of pointers. I prefer the second one because the addresses are contiguous, as you can see in the image.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(){

    int **arr_01,**arr_02,i,j,rows=4,cols=5;

    //Implementation 1
    arr_01=new int*[rows];

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        arr_01[i]=new int[cols];

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
            cout << arr_01[i]+j << " " ;
        cout << endl;
    }


    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        delete[] arr_01[i];
    delete[] arr_01;


    cout << endl;
    //Implementation 2
    arr_02=new int*[rows];
    arr_02[0]=new int[rows*cols];
    for(int i=1;i<rows;i++)
        arr_02[i]=arr_02[0]+cols*i;

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            cout << arr_02[i]+j << " " ;
        cout << endl;
    }

    delete[] arr_02[0];
    delete[] arr_02;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below example may help,

```
int main(void)
{
    double **a2d = new double*[5]; 
    /* initializing Number of rows, in this case 5 rows) */
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a2d[i] = new double[3]; /* initializing Number of columns, in this case 3 columns */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            a2d[i][j] = 1; /* Assigning value 1 to all elements */
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << a2d[i][j] << endl;  /* Printing all elements to verify all elements have been correctly assigned or not */
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        delete[] a2d[i];

    delete[] a2d;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If your project is CLI (Common Language Runtime Support)**, then:

You can use the array class, not that one you get when you write:

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;
```

In other words, not the unmanaged array class you get when using the std namespace and when including the array header, not the unmanaged array class defined in the std namespace and in the array header, but the managed class array of the CLI.

with this class, you can create an array of any **rank** you want.

The following code below creates new two dimensional array of 2 rows and 3 columns and of type int, and I name it "arr":

```
array<int, 2>^ arr = gcnew array<int, 2>(2, 3);
```

Now you can access elements in the array, by name it and write **only one** squared parentheses `[]`, and inside them, add the row and column, and separate them with the comma `,`.

The following code below access an element in 2nd row and 1st column of the array I already created in previous code above:

```
arr[0, 1]
```

writing only this line is to read the value in that cell, i.e. get the value in this cell, but if you add the equal `=` sign, you are about to write the value in that cell, i.e. set the value in this cell.
You also can use the +=, -=, *= and /= operators of course, for numbers only (int, float, double, __int16, __int32, __int64 and etc), but sure you know it already.

If your project is **not** CLI, then you can use the unmanaged array class of the std namespace, if you `#include <array>`, of course, but the problem is that this array class is different than the CLI array. Create array of this type is same like the CLI, except that you will have to remove the `^` sign and the `gcnew` keyword. But unfortunately the second int parameter in the `<>` parentheses specifies the **length (i.e. size)** of the array, **not** its rank!

There is no way to specify rank in this kind of array, rank is CLI array's feature **only.**.

std array behaves like normal array in c++, that you define with pointer, for example `int*` and then: `new int[size]`, or without pointer: `int arr[size]`, but unlike the normal array of the c++, std array provides functions that you can use with the elements of the array, like fill, begin, end, size, and etc, but normal array provides **nothing**.

But still std array are one dimensional array, like the normal c++ arrays.
But thanks to the solutions that the other guys suggest about how you can make the normal c++ one dimensional array to two dimensional array, we can adapt the same ideas to std array, e.g. according to Mehrdad Afshari's idea, we can write the following code:

```
array<array<int, 3>, 2> array2d = array<array<int, 3>, 2>();
```

This line of code creates a **"jugged array"**, which is an one dimensional array that each of its cells is or points to another one dimensional array.

If all one dimensional arrays in one dimensional array are equal in their length/size, then you can treat the array2d variable as a real two dimensional array, plus you can use the special methods to treat rows or columns, depends on how you view it in mind, in the 2D array, that std array supports.

You also can use Kevin Loney's solution:

```
int *ary = new int[sizeX*sizeY];

// ary[i][j] is then rewritten as
ary[i*sizeY+j]
```

but if you use std array, the code must look different:

```
array<int, sizeX*sizeY> ary = array<int, sizeX*sizeY>();
ary.at(i*sizeY+j);
```

And still have the unique functions of the std array.

Note that you still can access the elements of the std array using the `[]` parentheses, and you don't have to call the `at` function.
You also can define and assign new int variable that will calculate and keep the total number of elements in the std array, and use its value, instead of repeating `sizeX*sizeY`

You can define your own two dimensional array generic class, and define the constructor of the two dimensional array class to receive two integers to specify the number of rows and columns in the new two dimensional array, and define get function that receive two parameters of integer that access an element in the two dimensional array and returns its value, and set function that receives three parameters, that the two first are integers that specify the row and column in the two dimensional array, and the third parameter is the new value of the element. Its type depends on the type you chose in the generic class.

You will be able to implement all this by using **either** the normal c++ array (pointers or without) **or** the std array and use one of the ideas that other people suggested, and make it easy to use like the cli array, or like the two dimensional array that you can define, assign and use in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an 2d array of integers, which elements are allocated sequentially in memory, you must declare it like

```
int (*intPtr)[n] = new int[x][n]
```

where instead of **x** you can write any dimension, but **n** must be the same in two places. Example

```
int (*intPtr)[8] = new int[75][8];
intPtr[5][5] = 6;
cout<<intPtr[0][45]<<endl;
```

must print 6.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure if the following answer wasn't provided
but I decided to add some local optimizations to the allocation of 2d array
(e.g., a square matrix is done through only one allocation):

`int** mat = new int*[n];
mat[0] = new int [n * n];`

However, deletion goes like this because of linearity of the allocation above:

`delete [] mat[0];
delete [] mat;`

Comment: Already mentioned in an answer to this very question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672888/103167 and a smart pointer version here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29375830/103167

Answer (score 1):

this is an old answer but I like to declarer dynamic arrays like this for C++

```
int sizeY,sizeX = 10;
 //declaring dynamic 2d array:
    int **ary = new int*[sizeY];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++) 
    {
     ary[i] = new int[sizeX];
   }
```

you can change the size in run time like this.
this is tested in c++ 98

Answer (score 0):

I have left you with a solution which works the best for me, in certain cases. Especially if one knows [the size of?] one dimension of the array. Very useful for an array of chars, for instance if we need an array of varying size of arrays of char[20].

```
int  size = 1492;
char (*array)[20];

array = new char[size][20];
...
strcpy(array[5], "hola!");
...
delete [] array;
```

The key is the parentheses in the array declaration.

Comment: StackOverflow only uses English, please translate your question.

Answer (score 0):

I used this not elegant but FAST,EASY and WORKING system. I do not see why can not work because the only way for the system to allow create a big size array and access parts is without cutting it in parts:

```
#define DIM 3
#define WORMS 50000 //gusanos

void halla_centros_V000(double CENW[][DIM])
{
    CENW[i][j]=...
    ...
}


int main()
{
    double *CENW_MEM=new double[WORMS*DIM];
    double (*CENW)[DIM];
    CENW=(double (*)[3]) &CENW_MEM[0];
    halla_centros_V000(CENW);
    delete[] CENW_MEM;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining the array using pointers (Line 1):

```
int** a = new int* [x];     //x is the number of rows
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    a[i] = new int[y];     //y is the number of columns
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to declare a pre-defined pointer array:

```
int **x;
x = new int*[2] { 
        new int[2] { 0, 1 },
        new int[2] { 2, 3 } 
    };
```

access:

```
cout << x[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the array locally or inside a class, you can use lambda expression to create an array-like object.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  srand(time(0));
  int w = rand() % 20 + 10;
  int h = rand() % 20 + 10;
  {
    // Here. Only one line and no memory leak.
    auto arr = [=, p = std::make_unique<int[]>(w * h)](int i, int j) -> int & { return *&p[i * w + j]; };
    arr(1, 0) = 6;
    std::cout << arr(1, 0) << '\n';
  }
}
```

The object is not compatible with `int[][]`, and to pass it as an argument, you will need templates. But it can release you from the trouble of getting `[i * w + j]` right when you access an element.

You can also use a bare `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` along with a getter implemented in lambda. But you may make mistakes and have dangling references.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment yet, but I really liked @Ben_Voigt's comment on @kamshi's answer.  It took me a while to figure out how to implement Ben's suggestions, so I thought I'd post the code:

```
    auto temp = std::make_unique<unsigned int[]>(sizeX * sizeY);
    auto array2d = std::make_unique<unsigned int* []>(sizeX);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i)
        array2d[i] = (&temp[0] + i * sizeX);
```

BTW, here is why I like this code:

I want to use modern C++ as much as possible.

std::array is allocated on the stack, and memory for 2D arrays is allocated contiguously, which I need.  Unfortunately, my arrays are too large to fit comfortably in the stack (>100kB).

std::vector is allocated on the heap, which is good, but when you allocate a 2D vector like this:

```
vector<vector<double>> A(NR, vector<double>(NC, 0.0));
```

the rows are not contiguous in memory.  I'm using BLAS (Intel MKL) for matrix operations, so the memory must be contiguous.

The std::mdspan looks like it fulfills my needs, but Microsoft does not yet support it.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

declaring 2D array dynamically:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int x = 3, y = 3;

        int **ptr = new int *[x];

        for(int i = 0; i<y; i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = new int[y];
        }
        srand(time(0));

        for(int j = 0; j<x; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k<y; k++)
            {
                int a = rand()%10;
                ptr[j][k] = a;
                cout<<ptr[j][k]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Now in the above code we took a double pointer and assigned it a dynamic memory and gave a value of the columns. Here the memory allocated is only for the columns, now for the rows we just need a for loop and assign the value for every row a dynamic memory. Now we can use the pointer just the way we use a 2D array. In the above example we then assigned random numbers to our 2D array(pointer).Its all about DMA of 2D array.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using 2D vectors over 2D arrays. Basically using vectors as much as possible mostly because

1. dynamic memory allocation is hassle-free
2. automatic memory management

here is a small code snippet where you can create a dynamic sized array

```
vector<vector<int>> arr;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{    
    vector<int> temp;
    for (int j=0; j<k; j++)
    {
        int val;
        //assign values
        temp.push_back(val);
    }
    arr.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int **arr = new int* [NoOfRows]
for(int i = 0; i<NoOfRows; i++)
   arr[i] = new int[noOfColumn];
```

This is the good way to declare the 2D array in c++ using new
Here NoOfRow is showing that how many rows you want
ans noOfColumn is showing how many column you want

Comment: This is almost identical to an earlier answer.

Answer (score -4):

I'm using this when creating dynamic array. If you have a class or a struct. And this works. Example:

```
struct Sprite {
    int x;
};

int main () {
   int num = 50;
   Sprite **spritearray;//a pointer to a pointer to an object from the Sprite class
   spritearray = new Sprite *[num];
   for (int n = 0; n < num; n++) {
       spritearray[n] = new Sprite;
       spritearray->x = n * 3;
  }

   //delete from random position
    for (int n = 0; n < num; n++) {
        if (spritearray[n]->x < 0) {
      delete spritearray[n];
      spritearray[n] = NULL;
        }
    }

   //delete the array
    for (int n = 0; n < num; n++) {
      if (spritearray[n] != NULL){
         delete spritearray[n];
         spritearray[n] = NULL;
      }
    }
    delete []spritearray;
    spritearray = NULL;

   return 0;
  }
```