# Very large array on the heap (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I hope some one can help me, i'm trying to create an int[400000000] (400 millions) array on my application using visual c++ 2010 but it generates an overflow error
The same code runs on linux with g++. 
I need this because i'm working with large matrices.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you trying to create it dynamically?

Comment: Maybe if you share the core problem you're trying to solve, we will be able to be of more assistance.

Comment: On some systems there is a limit on the size of the stack frame. You could be running into this. Use std::vector<> to see if this solves the problem (otherwise you are just plain running out of memory.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c/216731#216731

Answer (score 14):

If you are using a 32-bit application then by default you have just 2GB of user address space. 400 million integers is about 1.5GB. You are very likely not to have this much contiguous address space. It is possible to force 32-bit windows to allocate a 3GB user address space for each process but this may just be a stop gap for your situation.

If you can move to a 64-bit architecture then this should not be an issue; otherwise you should find a way of storing your matrix data in a way that does not require a single block of contiguous storage, for example storing it in chunks.

Comment: +1, yup.  650 MB is about all you can expect.  Storing a matrix in a smarter data structure is *very* important for speed as well.

Comment: For speed it depends on your access patterns. For a straight linear pass through the data, the difference between the operating system paging out old pages and a manual caching strategy may be nothing. If (e.g.!) you're perfoming matrix multiplication on 20000 x 20000 matrices it's very difficult to come up with a fast strategy as you need to combine numbers from all areas of the matrices in all combinations.

Comment: @Charles: Not *that* difficult. Just need to use blocking :)

Comment: @jalf: Just so I'm clear, what do you mean by 'blocking' in this context?

Comment: @Charles: http://netlib.org/utk/papers/autoblock/node2.html for example -- basically split the matrix into smaller blocks (sized to fit in cache, or main memory), and do as much work on a single block as possible before swapping it out for the next one. A common way to get better cache behavior on algorithms such as matrix multiplication

Comment: @jalf: I must admit that I haven't ever had the need to implement a blocked algorithm for matrix multiplication but my impression was that you'd very quickly need to combine (i.e. add the results) of blocks generated by multiplying sub-blocks from across the address range so it's not obvious to me that significant speed gains are easy to obtain.

Comment: @Charles: I think we're veering off topic here, but it does dramatically cut down on the number of cache misses (or page faults or whatever you're trying to avoid). Assuming of course that those are what's limiting your performance, it's a very useful family of optimizations. I used variations of it on a few research projects as a student, and the speed gain can be significant, but it depends a lot on the hardware, and the size of your input and so on

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is a Divide-and-Conquer algorithm. Not memory space.

Comment: This is not helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if in you're case it wouldn't even be better to use [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [sparse matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) are of use in your application. This concept is used when dealing with big matrices which have a lot of 0 entries, which can be the case in quite a lot of applications.

And by the way, you do not gain anything by storing such a huge amount of data on the heap. Consider, that your CPU cache has perhaps 12 MB! At least use some intelligent dynamic memory allocation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Does the whole array really needs to be allocated ? do you really use the whole array ? Is it an array with lots of 0 ? if it is the case, then the fact that it works better on linux can be explained.

In that case using a sparse array might be more appropriate. Using an existing sparse array implementation would reduce the memory footprint and maybe allow faster computation.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very simple solution but i don't know if it is advisable

```
int tab[400000000]={0};//global array

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
std::cout<<tab[399999999]<<std::endl;//ok

/*
int* tab=new int[400000000];//doesn't work
...
delete[] tab;
*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution here is to grab the address space really early.  Don't rely on this working for such a large block on 32bits it will be fragile to the environment.