# Debugging without Debugging Symbols

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a c++ project where the beahviour in debug and release mode differs. E.g. in release mode i get bad alloc errors wheras in debug mode everthing runs fine. Maybe this difference comes from different runtime speed.

Do you have any tips and hints how to debug a program without a standard debugger (like gdb)? I could try to cout a lot in critical areas but that seems not be the smartest way to go... Maybe there is a way to get some information about locations of some kinds of errors without using debugging symbols? Are there any tools?

Comment: are you sure the difference is casued by debugging symbol? what are the compile commands to generate debug/release binaries?

Comment: You can have debugging symbols available in a release build and it shouldn't change the behavior of the program at all.  If you're having issues between debug/release builds then it's likely you have some undefined behavior or uninitialized variables that are causing issues.

Comment: Is a bad alloc error an exception? Can you catch and log the exception with a stacktrace? How much memory does each version actually use?

Comment: Just adding `-g` to release build's flags shouldn't change a thing in execution flow. If it does - this thing needs to be debugged. Meanwhile, you could try using separate debugging symbol map file, gdb supports this.

Comment: Kinda related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386291/c-program-dies-with-stdbad-alloc-but-valgrind-reports-no-memory-leaks

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a stack trace from the crash, you may be able to symbolicate it later. For example, on MacOS there's the tool `atos` which, according to the `man` page:

> converts numeric addresses to their symbolic equivalents.

This would allow you to run without symbols, but use them later.

Comment: For GNU toolchain, equivalent would be `addr2line`. This, however, only partially related to question.