# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) (why though??)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So i was solving my homework, and i did this piece of code which is supposed to find the biggest difference beetween two prime numbers in the interval of [a,b], and i got "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;
bitset <10000000>v;
int main()
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int j = i * i; j < 10000000; j += i)
                v[j] = 1;
        }
    }
    int n, a, b, maxi = 0, mini = 0, smax = 0;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int poz = a;
    while (v[poz] == 1)
        poz++;
    int prev = poz;
    poz++;
    while (v[poz] == 1 && poz < b)
        poz++;
    if (poz == b && v[b] == 1)
    {
        cout << -1; return 0;
    }
    int next = poz;
    poz++;
    while (poz <= b)
    {
        if (next - prev > smax)
        {
            smax = next - prev;
            maxi = next;
            mini = prev;
        }
        if (v[poz] == 0)
        {
            prev = next;
            next = poz;
        }
        poz++;
    }
    cout << mini << " " << maxi;
    return 0;
}
```

i expected 43 with 47

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629712/simple-array-cause-exception)

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: i guess the task is about biggest difference between two consecutive prime numbers, otherwise it is just the difference between the first and the last prime

Comment: @Scamtex This is not a problem, due to 1) `v` not being on the stack; 2) Asker not getting stack overflow, but rather access violation.

Comment: Try searching for the return value (both decimal and hexadecimal). It should give you some hints.

Comment: `0xC0000005` = Access Violation

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: You have to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program. Primarily, you should use a debugger to catch the crash "in action", and then you will be able to pinpoint where in your code it happens, as well as be able to examine your variables and their values to make sure they are okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your initialisation loop when `i` is `46349`, `i*i` is `2,148,229,801`, this is larger than fits inside a signed 32-bit integer so evaluates to `-2,146,737,495`. `v[j]` then causes the crash.

You should either modify your code to use a larger data type or set the limit for `i` to `sqrt(10000000)` rather than `10000000`.

Comment: No, `i*i` is correct for the sieve.  When considering multiples of 5, you don't need to consider 5x2, or 5x3 (they will have been eliminated as multiple of 2 and 3), - you start at 5x5.  (Point is though, that similarly you don't need to consider values of `i` above sqrt(10million) ).

Comment: ok, was just going by wikipedia which says to start at 2p in step 3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Works on my machine.  However, I'm using 64-bit int.  I think it will fail on machines using 32-bit int.

Comment: @Eljay What compiler are you using that has 64-bit *int* ?  (64-bit pointers and longs, sure - but int ??!?)

Comment: @MartinBonner • a modified version of clang.  I'm also using separate heaps for `malloc`, `new` and `new[]`.

Comment: 64-bit int --   int64_t, include < cstdint >

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `i*i` overflows when `i` is large, leading to a negative value for `j` and an access violation on `v[j]=1;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a potential segmentation fault on line `v[j]=1;` where `j` may exceed `10000000`.

Please check your boundaries.