# is malloc better than declaring?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between declaration and malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575544/difference-between-declaration-and-malloc)

what's the difference between:

```
char * a = malloc(size);
```

and

```
char a[size];
```

Is one better than the other? is there any advantage at all in using malloc?

Comment: Note that you want `char a[size]` instead of pointer.

Comment: One is sane, the other will invariably lead to broken code if you're not an absolutely awesome programmer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't control the life-time scope of stack allocated memory, it's only valid for as long as the scope (unless you make it static).

`malloc` is for allocating memory on the heap. It's valid until you call `free` on that memory.

It's faster to allocate memory on the stack, normally because you're not actually allocating new memory you're just reserving more of what you're already using but you don't control the life-time, it controlled by the scope of your block or function.

Comment: wow thank you so much for the fast answer! can you give me an example  where malloc works better? If it's not asking too much, because I'd like to know in which cases the declaration would fail

Comment: Stack allocations fails when there's no stack space left, infinite recursion results in the same problem, stack overflow. Heap allocation gives you access to the heap, it's probably a lot larger than the stack space you have reserved but not infinite or without it's problems. Use the heap when you intend to share things for longer periods of time but be mindful of things like heap fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

> what's the difference between `char *a = malloc(size);` and char *a[size];`?

The first one declares a pointer to `char` and allocates `size` bytes for it on the heap. The second one allocates `size` pieces of `char` pointers. They're not equivalent.

> Is the one better than the other?

No, they have different uses.

> Is there any advantage at all in using `malloc()`?

Yes. If you want to return an array from a function, you can't do this:

```
char a[size];
return a;
```

because then `a` is out of scope after the return, and using it results in undefined behavior. So in this case you must use

```
char *a = malloc(size);
return a;
```

(Generally this is the case, since you would presumably want to return a new string each time from a function - however, if this is not a requirement, you can use a static array, declared locally.)

However, if the array is only to be used locally, then it's generally advisable to use auto (stack) arrays and not `malloc()` because that avoids increasing memory fragmentation and stack operations can be faster than heap access.

Comment: "If you want to return an array from a function, ...,  you must use ... " isn't entirely correct -- `static char a[size]; return a;` should also work.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen I didn't write "you can't do `static char a[size];`", I wrote "you can't do `char a[size];`"...

Comment: @JoshuaGreen In other words, declaring an array with the `static` keyword does not result in an auto array, since its storage duration is static...

Comment: I was disagreeing with the claim that one "must use `char *a = malloc(size); return a;`" by providing an alternative.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen Now it's precise, updated.

Comment: I would also mention that usually there is a bigger chance to have cache hits in the stack.