# Do I have to free the memory alloc by C in Xcode iOS project?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I know the memory allocated dynamically as follow can be free like below:

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
memset(array,0,sizeof(int) * 100);
// use the array
free(array);
```

(Is the example above applied to C++ only or both C and C++?)

But I do not know if I have to free it when it is used like below (plain C language):

```
int array[3];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 1;
array[2] = 2;
```

And what is the difference between the two methods to create an array?

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to free the array in your second example, as you are not malloc'ing it.

About the difference:

[Difference between declaration and malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575544/difference-between-declaration-and-malloc)

In C++ you usually want to use new/delete, but malloc/free also work.