# What is the difference between malloc and array

Tags: arrays, malloc

I want to ask about malloc and array.

int *x;

x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

and

int x[4];

what is the difference between them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between declaration and malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575544/difference-between-declaration-and-malloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are multiple differences.

This allocates a buffer of one `int` on the heap...

```
int *x;
x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

And this allocates an array of four `int`s either on the stack or in global memory, or perhaps declares it as a member of a struct or class, if it appears within the definition of a struct or class...

```
int x[4];
```

Other than the location of the allocations, the first allocated space for one `int` and the second allocated space for four `int`s. But assuming you meant to do this instead...

```
int *x;
x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
```

...then in that case, both allocations are a block of memory that is four times the size of an `int` on your platform. And from a usage standpoint, you can then use them both in pretty much the same way; `x[0]` is the first `int` in either case, and since neither are declared `const`, you can read or write to either in the same way.

So now we get to the difference in the allocation characteristics & lifetime of the two different ways of allocating that memory:

In the `malloc()`'ed case, memory for that request is allocated on the heap, and its lifetime is however long you want to keep it until you call `free()` on it. In the other case, if you declared it as a local variable inside a method/function, its lifetime is until program execution exits the scope in which it was declared. If you declared it as a global variable, its lifetime is the lifetime of the entire application. And if you declared it as a member variable of a struct or class, then its lifetime is that of its enclosing struct/class, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 1):

The most important difference between `int *xp;` and `int xa[4];` is `sizeof(xp) != sizeof(xa)` the size of the declared object.

You can pass the `xa` object as `int *pparam` to a function, but you cannot pass `xp` as a `int aparam[4]` to a function, as aparam describes the whole 4 int object and pparam describes a pointer to an object that might have any length.

Also `xa` will be reserved in the data area of the linked program, while the pointer `malloc(sizeof(int)*4)` will be allocated by a system call at runtime and on the heap. Check the vast address difference in a debugger!

Comment: Ahh.. yes.. sizeof(). I had forgotten that. Of course `sizeof(xp[0]) == sizeof(xa[0])`. And you got me too on passing them as parameters to a function. Upvote.