# Multi-dimensional primitive integer array

Tags: objective-c, primitive-types

I know this code doesn't work, but how could I actually initialize this correctly?:

```
NSUInteger highestModelID = 34605;
NSUInteger highestColorID = 328;
NSUInteger** modelColors[highestModelID][highestColorID] = malloc(highestModelID * highestColorID * sizeof(NSUInteger));
```

So having 2 dynamic depths. I have this massive buffer in a multi-dimensional `NSMutableDictionary` which hogs memory. I would really love to just do this primitive.

Guess it would be even more amazing to make a class out of this to be able to use it on more places where Objective-C dictionaries and even `NSMutableArray` are really just overkill. Over time I'm really becoming more and more annoyed by using `NSNumber` for something that would be super light what I'm used to in `golang`, suddenly making it a major factor in slowing my app down..

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575544/difference-between-declaration-and-malloc. Basically if you're malloc'ing the memory, you need to remove the `[highestModelID][highestColorID]` suffix on your `modelColors` declaration – as that's used for c arrays with automatic storage.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I hardly ever use native C anymore. I think the last time I seriously used low-level C was 17 years ago in Visual Basic 6(?). I guess it's good to maybe do some oldschool NASM/C tuts again just to get the hang of it again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
NSUInteger* modelColors = malloc(highestModelID * highestColorID * sizeof(NSUInteger));
```

Which you can use like this:

```
NSUInteger getModelColor(int modelID, int colorID, int highestModelID,  NSUInteger* modelColors) {
    return modelColors[colorID * highestModelID + modelID];
}

void setModelColor(NSUInteger color, int modelID, int colorID, int highestModelID,  NSUInteger* modelColors) {
    modelColors[colorID * highestModelID + modelID] = color;
}
```

Basically this is a 2D array, where `modelID` indexes the rows, and `colorID` indexes the columns (assuming row-major layout).

Comment: Cool this works perfect. I'm gonna embed it in a class called `EB2DArray` so I can easily remember those 2 highest ID's for the rest of the array's lifespan, making it easier to just do `get*` and `set*` by only giving the `modelID` and `colorID`. Opens a lot of possibilities for different typed arrays too. Thanks!

Comment: It's my own responsibility to free the array isn't it? I know ARC doesn't see the `@property` inside my class as part of the `EB2DArray` object I would make. Maybe I need to override `dealloc` to specifically call `free()` on the `@property` that holds the array `- (void)dealloc { free(self.theArray); }`?

Comment: I might've missed something here, but for some reason when having the logic inside my class, the fetching of the NSUInteger doesn't work :(. Maybe I missed something: http://pastebin.com/fRbBncQd ?

Comment: Oh gosh lol, never mind me. The `intSetAtLevel1Key` was `level2Key + self.level1Capacity + level1Key` but should've been `level2Key * self.level1Capacity + level1Key`.

Comment: Yep. And also I would recommend replacing the `create...` method with a proper initializer like: `-(instancetype)initWithLevel1Capacity:(NSUInteger)level1Capacity level2Capacity:(NSUInteger)level2Capacity`

Comment: Thanks! Changed that too. Looks nice and tidy in my main code now :)

Comment: Hmm I'm getting bad access if I do `free(self.theArray)` and then `malloc` it again and try to access entries from it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Z3qP995D pasted the class and the code that tries to call it, never on the first run. It always happens when it gets called again. I tried a reset call because `nil`ing it doesn't seem to work correctly either. It's inside my Core singleton object so it's there the whole lifespan of the app. It crashes on the `setIntValue` method after the first time called.

Comment: The initializer was not right, fixed that. Also added some sanity-checks in the indexing methods: http://pastebin.com/c8wkCBhg Also, don't bother with `reset`, just create a new array – this will deallocate the old one and create a new one, just like your tried with `reset`, but it's less code.

Comment: Shouldn't the `init`-call be `+` (class-method)? Also the self cannot be accessed so it's giving errors. How can I properly instantiate it? :)

Comment: Nope. `init` is always an instance method (prefixed with `-`). Just look into any of the Apple headers and you'll see.

Comment: Works now! Was a small typo in the example.

Comment: This is quite strange, b/c it's declared in the class extension. Aka the `@interface AM2DArray()` part.

Comment: Yeah it was just variable wrongly named. I also had to do  `highestModelID + 1` and `highestColorID + 1` because it can exactly hit out of range on the highest value. Works stable so far :)

Answer (score 2):

The way of creating it isn't really that different from creating NSArray of NSArrays. You need to alloc array of NSUInteger* first, then alloc each of its elements.

```
NSUInteger  **modelColors;
modelColors = malloc(highestModelID * sizeof(NSUInteger*));
for (int i = 0; i < highestModelID; i++) {
    modelColors[i] = malloc(highestColorID * sizeof(NSUInteger));
}
```

Comment: Wrong. You're doing `highestModelID` allocations, while this can be done with a single `malloc` of size `highestModelID * highestColorID`.

Comment: Premature optimization? :D OP's primary concern was memory usage. You're probably aware that `malloc` doesn't allocate the exact number of bytes you're asking for, but rounds it up to the closest size class. Therefore using `highestModelID` number of allocations, you're wasting N * `highestModelID` bytes. (where N is the difference between `highestColorID` and the closest size class)

Comment: @TamásZahola Ah, didn't see the memory concern in the question, my bad!