# How does memory allocation in malloc differs from that of an array?

Tags: c

I have written a code like this:

```
int * ptr;
ptr = (int*) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

Please tell me how memory is allocated to "ptr" using this malloc function?
How is it different from memory allocation in an integer array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between declaration and malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575544/difference-between-declaration-and-malloc)

Comment: [Also casting malloc is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Answer in terms of the language

It differs in the *storage duration*. If you use an integer array, it could be at the file scope (outside any function):

```
int arr[5];
```

This has *static* storage duration, which means the object is alive for the whole execution time of the program.

The other possibility is inside a function:

```
void foo(void)
{
    int arr[5];
}
```

This variant has *automatic* storage duration, so the object is only alive as long as the program execution is inside this function (more generally: inside the scope of the variable which is the enclosing pair of braces: `{ ... }`)

If you use `malloc()` instead, the object has *dynamic* storage duration. This means *you* decide for how long the object is alive. It stays alive until you call `free()` on it.

#### 2. Answer in terms of the OS

`malloc()` is typically implemented on the *heap*. This is an area of your address space where your program can dynamically request more memory from the OS.

In contrast, with an object with *automatic* storage duration, typical implementations place it on the *stack* (where a new frame is created for each function call) and with *static* storage duration, it will be in a data segment of your program already from the start.

This part of the answer is intentionally a bit vague; C implementations exist for a vast variety of systems, and while *stack*, *heap* and *data segments* are used in many modern operating systems with virtual memory management, they are by no means required -- take for example embedded platforms and microcontrollers where your program might run without any operating system. So, writing portable C code, you should (most of the time) only be interested in what the language specifies.

Answer (score 4):

The C standard is very clear on this.

1. The memory pointed to by `ptr` has *dynamic storage duration*.
2. The memory associated with an `int foo[5];`, say has *automatic storage duration*.

The key difference between the two is that in the dynamic case you need to call `free` on `ptr` to release the memory once you're done with it, whereas `foo` will be released automatically once it goes out of *scope*.

The mechanism for acquiring the memory in either case is intentionally left to the compiler.

For further research, Google the terms that I've *italicised*.