# Is malloc neccesary when creating array in function call?

Tags: c

I have a function call

```
void copy_data(FILE *fin, FILE *fout, int size) {
     char buf[size];
     memset(buf, 0, size);
     fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, fin);
     fwrite(buf, sizeof buf, 1, fout);

}
```

Is malloc here necessary, because I read that I need to use malloc when I don't know the size at compile time which I don't know here, but I feel like malloc is not neccesary here.

Comment: Umm..   where is the malloc?

Comment: I am not using the malloc here because I think I can create array just like this? That's why I am asking if I should be using malloc here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not necesssary here provided that you are not going to use large amount of memory. Data related to this function will be allocated on a stack together with other variables (you are putting `size` elements of type `char` on the stack). You might, however [take these points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575576/4765864) into consideration. If you want to use heap which is bigger, you would need to use `malloc()` and then manually free the memory.

**EDIT**
As it has been pointed out, the C11 standard makes Variable Length Arrays optional, so problem of portability of your code also comes accross.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks for mentioning it. I've made an update.

Answer (score 4):

C99 and later allow variable length arrays (VLA). `buf` is a variable length array and if the `size` is small you can use it. For large size (stack size limitations)  arrays you need to allocate memory dynamically.

Note that since C11, VLA is made optional.

Comment: It is not an extension, it is an optional feature and gcc supports it.

Comment: @JensGustedt; The thing is GCC supports VLA in C90 as an extension and I thought it is also an extension for C99 an later.