# Is there any limitation of array length in C?

Tags: c

I'm working on a program in C. I want to initialize an array which has a length of 1,000,000
It compiles without any errors or warnings but in the execution, windows sends a process termination.
I modified my code so there will be 4 arrays each having 500,000 integers. It again compiles without error or warning but the problem still exists.

I use CodeBlox (GCC compiler, I think)

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
// Prototypes:
int checkprime(int n);

int main(){
int m=0;

    int A[500001]={2,2,0};//from k=1 to 500000
    int B[500000]={0};//from k=500001 to 1000000
    int C[500000]={0};//from k=1000001 to 1500000
    int D[500000]={0};//from k=1500001 to 2000000
    int n=3;
    int k=2;
        for(n=3;n<2000001;n +=2){
            if(checkprime(n)){

                if (k<=500000)
                {A[k]=n;
                k +=1;}

                else if ((k>500000)&&(k<=1000000))
                {B[k-500001]=n;
                k +=1;}
                else if ((k>1000000)&&(k<=1500000)){
                C[k-1000001]=n;
                    k +=1;
                }
                else if(k>1500000){
                D[k-1500001]=n;
                k +=1;}
                }//end of if

            }//end for

    int i=0;
    for(i=1;i<500001;i++)
    {
        m=m+A[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<5000001;i++)
    {
        m=m+B[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<5000001;i++)
    {
        m=m+C[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<5000001;i++)
    {
        m=m+D[i];
    }
    printf("answer is %d",m);
return 0;//Successful end indicator
}//end of main

int checkprime(int n){
int m=sqrt(n);
if (!(m%2))
{
    m=m+1;
}
int stop=0;
int d=0;
int isprime=1;
while((m!=1)&&(stop==0)){
d=n%m;
if (d==0){
    stop=1;
    isprime=0;
    }
m -=2;

}//end of while
return isprime;
}//end of checkprime
```

Comment: re: array length limit, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c

Comment: @H2CO3: yes, it is.  It certainly depends on whether the array is static or not, and might depend on whether it is in data or bss.

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course it is needed. The OP's program is crashing and we don't know why without seeing the code.

Comment: @H2CO3,@KeithRandall: I uploaded my code. Does it have anything to do with m being a 4 byte int?

Comment: You should use `calloc`  for your big array.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your huge initialized array is static or global. If it is a local variable it would overflow the stack at runtime.

I believe that old versions of GCC had sub-optimal behavior (perhaps quadratic time) when initializing an array.

I also believe that the *C* standard might define a (small) minimal array size which all conforming compilers should accept (there is such a lower limit for string sizes, it might be as small as 512).

IIRC, recent versions of GCC improved their behavior when initializing static arrays. Try with GCC 4.7

With my Debian/Sid's `gcc-4.7.1` I am able to compile a `biga.c` file starting with

```
int big[] = {2 ,
 3 ,
 5 ,
 7 ,
 11 ,
 13 ,
```

and ending with

```
 399999937 ,
 399999947 ,
 399999949 ,
 399999959 ,
};
```

and containing 23105402 lines:

```
 % time gcc -c biga.c
 gcc -c biga.c  43.51s user 1.87s system 96% cpu 46.962 total

 % /usr/bin/time -v gcc -O2 -c biga.c
Command being timed: "gcc -O2 -c biga.c"
User time (seconds): 48.99
System time (seconds): 2.10
Percent of CPU this job got: 97%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:52.59
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 5157040
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 691666
Voluntary context switches: 25
Involuntary context switches: 5162
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 32
File system outputs: 931512
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

This is on a i7 3770K desktop with 16Gb RAM.

Having **huge arrays as locals**, even inside `main`  **is** always **a bad idea**. Either heap-allocate them (e.g. with `calloc` or `malloc`, then `free` them appropriately) or make them global or static. Space for local data on call stack is always a scare resource. A typical call frame (combined size of all local variables) should be less than a kilobyte. A call frame bigger than a megabyte is almost always bad and un-professional.

Comment: Do you know any modern C environment which handles these stuff efficiently?(except MS Visual or Dev) Does programming on a Linux based OS have this runtime problems too?

Comment: The problem is in your code. Even Linux have stack size limits (but you could configure them).

Answer (score 1):

Limit on maximum stack size controlled with ulimit command. Compiler can (or not) set limit smaller, but not bigger than that.
To see current limit (in kilobytes):

```
ulimit -s
```

To remove limit:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

Comment: In your case, better learn to use `calloc` and `free`. In general, there is always some limit on the stack size.

Comment: @PooyaMoradi: - yes, in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

Local arrays are created on the stack, and if your array is too large, the stack will collide with something else in memory and crash the program.

Comment: No! arrays declared `static` are *not* stack-allocated!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't mean arrays declared as 'static'. I mean statically allocated arrays.

Comment: These are not called statically allocated, but local arrays.

Comment: statically allocated arrays are *statically* allocated; that is, they are allocated at compile or link time. Anything created on the stack is *dynamically* allocated.

Comment: @JimBalter glad to see this, me too.