# What is the maximal array size in C?

Tags: c, arrays, limits

I wonder what is the maximal array size in C, weither it depends on the type of data, and if it depends where it is declared (heap or stack).

The following code works with `int` up to a size of 1048576 (2^20), also 1048577 (same + 1), but not with 2097152 (2^21) - I have not searched for the precise limit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 1048577llu /* 2097152llu */

int main()
{
    int tab[MAX];
    /* long long int tab[MAX] */
    tab[MAX - 1] = 123;
    printf("tab[%llu] declared, tab[%llu] = %d\n", MAX, MAX - 1, tab[MAX - 1]); 
    return 0;
}
```

With `long long int`, it fails at 2^20, but succeeds at 2^19.

Comment: Frequently asked: local variables are usually placed on the stack, which has limited capacity.

Comment: However much space your stack has probably. (It will vary between compilers and architectures.)

Comment: Terrible duplicate. This is as much as to do with a theoretical limit; and I couldn’t see a good fit for that.

Comment: There are some other relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753036/what-maximum-size-of-static-arrays-are-allowed-in-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698811/is-there-any-limitation-of-array-length-in-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c (note last one is actually C++) that should help

Comment: @Bathsheba then rewind it. The question is about local variable storage, not theoretical limits.

Comment: @WeatherVane: that’s a crying shame. Think I’ll hang my tools up for the day!

Comment: And the new duplicate has an answer superior to mine.

Comment: @Bathsheba soneone else did it, but the question does ask if it depends where the array is stored.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Not trying to step on any toes here. I couldn't find an exact duplicate, but the subject roughly divides into questions about stack limits, heap limits, and implementation limits.