# Maximum amount of data that can be sent using MPI::Send

Tags: c++, mpi

With the syntax for MPI::Isend as

```
MPI::Request MPI::Comm::Isend(const void *buf, int count, 
              const MPI::Datatype& datatype, 
              int dest, int tag) const;
```

is the amount of data sent limited by

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
```

Many other MPI functions have int parameter. Is this a limitation of MPI?

Comment: on a side note the C++ syntax of MPI are deprecated, you should use the C syntax

Answer (score 12):

MPI-2.2 defines data length parameters as `int`. This could be and usually is a problem on most 64-bit Unix systems since `int` is still 32-bit. Such systems are referred to as LP64, which means that `long` and pointers are 64-bit long, while `int` is 32-bit in length. In contrast, Windows x64 is an LLP64 system, which means that both `int` and `long` are 32-bit long while `long long` and pointers are 64-bit long. Linux for 64-bit x86 CPUs is an example of such a Unix-like system which is LP64.

Given all of the above `MPI_Send` in MPI-2.2 implementations have a message size limit of `2^31-1` elements. One can overcome the limit by constructing a user-defined type (e.g. a contiguous type), which would reduce the amount of data elements. For example, if you register a contiguous type of `2^10` elements of some basic MPI type and then you use `MPI_Send` to send `2^30` elements of this new type, it would result in a message of `2^40` elements of the basic type. Some MPI implementations may still fail in such cases if they use `int` to handle elements count internally. Also it breaks `MPI_Get_elements` and `MPI_Get_count` as their output `count` argument is of type `int`.

MPI-3.0 addresses some of these issues. For example, it provides the `MPI_Get_elements_x` and `MPI_Get_count_x` operations which use the `MPI_Count` typedef for their `count` argument. `MPI_Count` is defined so as to be able to hold pointer values, which makes it 64-bit long on most 64-bit systems. There are other extended calls (all end in `_x`) that take `MPI_Count` instead of `int`. The old `MPI_Get_elements` / `MPI_Get_count` operations are retained, but now they would return `MPI_UNDEFINED` if the count is larger than what the `int` output argument could hold (this clarification is not present in the MPI-2.2 standard and using very large counts in undefined behaviour there).

As pyCthon has already noted, the C++ bindings are deprecated in MPI-2.2 and were removed from MPI-3.0 as no longer supported by the MPI Forum. You should either use the C bindings or resort to 3rd party C++ bindings, e.g. `Boost.MPI`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer :) Is there any reason why C++ binding are deprecated?

Comment: @SumanVajjala, it's all in the MPI Forum tickets. [This one](https://svn.mpi-forum.org/trac/mpi-forum-web/ticket/150) contains most of the reasons why the C++ bindings were deprecated in MPI-2.2, [this one](https://svn.mpi-forum.org/trac/mpi-forum-web/ticket/281) contains the rationale behind removing them in MPI-3.0, and [this one](https://svn.mpi-forum.org/trac/mpi-forum-web/ticket/156) makes for some funny reading :)

Comment: Thanks @ Hristo for the links!!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done MPI, however, int is the usual limiting size of an array, and I would suspect that is where the limitation comes from.

In practice, this is a fairly high limit.  Do you have a need to send more than 4 GB of data? (In a single Isend)

For more information, please see [Is there a max array length limit in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c)

Do note that link makes references to size_t, rather than int (Which, for all intents, allows almost unlimited data, at least, in 2012) - however, in the past, 'int' was the usual type for such counts, and while size_t should be used, in practice, a lot of code is still using 'int'.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of an `MPI_Send` will be limited by the maximum amount of memory you can allocate

and most MPI implementations support`sizeof(size_t)`

Comment: Feel free to copy mine into your answer so that there's one clear 'good answer' - you seem to know MPI a bit better than I do. :)

Comment: @pyCthon It is not reflected in the syntax then? Or is it? I am confused:) I have an MPI code where I pack data using MPI::Pack and the datatype for the position in the buffer works only with int.    void MPI::Datatype::Pack(const void* inbuf, int incount, void* outbuf, 
    int outsize, int& position, const MPI::Comm& comm) 
    const;

Comment: @SumanVajjala: pyCtyhon has already pointed out that the C++ interface is deprecated (although I haven't confirmed myself, but I'd listen to the guy who has done MPI rather than I!).  As a tip, C and C++ are distinct languages, and if you are using namespaces, such as that 'MPI::' thing you have there, you are most certainly NOT using C.

Comment: @Arafangion the mpi standards committee did a survey a while back of who actually used the c++ syntax and it turns out there wasn't any one really using it at the time so they stopped updating it. I know for a fact Open MPI support size_t not sure of other implementations, the C syntax works fine in a C++ program

Comment: This is either inadequate or wrong.  If you mean to say that MPI_Send can  in theory send a buffer requiring the entire allocatable memory, then this is true for more than 2^31 elements if and only if one uses user-defined datatypes carefully.  And at the writing of your post, MPICH and OpenMPI did not fully support 64-bit counts internally and thus would break with this usage.  Only very recently did MPICH become "count-safe".

Answer (score 0):

This issue and a number of workarounds (with code) are discussed on https://github.com/jeffhammond/BigMPI.  In particular, this project demonstrates how to send more than INT_MAX elements via user-defined datatypes.