# How do I remove the memory limit on openmpi processes?

Tags: python, pickle, openmpi, mpi4py

I'm running a process with mpirun and 2 cores and it gets killed at the point when I'm mixing values between the two processes. Both processes use about 15% of the machines memory and even though the memory will increase when mixing, there should still be plenty of memory left. So I'm assuming that there is a limit on the amount of memory used for passing messages in between the processes. **How do I find out what this limit is and how do I remove it?**

The error message that I'm getting when mpirun dies is this:

```
File "Comm.pyx", line 864, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.bcast (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:67787)
File "pickled.pxi", line 564, in mpi4py.MPI.PyMPI_bcast (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:31462)
File "pickled.pxi", line 93, in mpi4py.MPI._p_Pickle.alloc (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:26327)
SystemError: Negative size passed to PyBytes_FromStringAndSize
```

And this is the bit of the code that leads to the error:

```
sum_updates_j_k = numpy.zeros((self.col.J_total, self.K), dtype=numpy.float64))        
comm.Reduce(self.updates_j_k, sum_updates_j_k, op=MPI.SUM) 
sum_updates_j_k = comm.bcast(sum_updates_j_k, root=0)
```

The code usually works, it only runs into problems with larger amounts of data, which makes the size of the matrix that I'm exchanging between processes increase

Comment: This doesn't seem like a memory problem. What are the arguments of the broadcast call?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post above. Each process writes into its own matrix, then I'm adding them up and broadcast them back to every process.

Comment: How big is the matrix?

Comment: in this particular case the size of the matrix is 7659561*50, so it should occupy ~1,5 GB.

Comment: I guess the pickled size of the matrix object exceeds 2 GiB and this leads to a 32-bit integer overflow. At least it should explain the negative size error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is probably the following lines found in the code of `PyMPI_bcast()`:

```python
cdef int count = 0
...
if dosend: smsg = pickle.dump(obj, &buf, &count)  # <----- (1)
with nogil: CHKERR( MPI_Bcast(&count, 1, MPI_INT, # <----- (2)
                              root, comm) )
cdef object rmsg = None
if dorecv and dosend: rmsg = smsg
elif dorecv: rmsg = pickle.alloc(&buf, count)
...
```

What happens here is that the object is first serialised at `(1)` using `pickle.dump()` and then the length of the pickled stream is broadcasted at `(2)`.

There are two problems here and they both have to do with the fact that `int` is used for the length. The first problem is an integer cast inside `pickle.dump` and the other problem is that `MPI_INT` is used to transmit the length of the pickled stream. This limits the amount of data in your matrix to a certain size - namely the size that would result in a pickled object no bigger than 2 GiB (2<sup>31</sup>-1 bytes). Any bigger object would result in an integer overflow and thus negative values in `count`.

This is clearly not an MPI issue but rather a bug in (or a feature of?) `mpi4py`.

Comment: that makes sense.. thanks for spotting the problem! I guess I either need to send the matrix in two batches or find a better mpi implementation for python

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with mpi4py recently. As pointed out by Hristo Iliev in his answer, it's a pickle problem.

This can be avoided by **using the upper-case methods** `comm.Reduce()`, `comm.Bcast()`, etc., [which do not resort to pickle](https://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html), as opposed to lower-case methods like `comm.reduce()`. As a bonus, upper case methods should be a bit faster as well.

Actually, you're already using `comm.Reduce()`, so I expect that switching to `comm.Bcast()` should solve your problem - it did for me.

NB: The syntax of upper-case methods is slightly different, but [this tutorial](http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/collectiveCom.html) can help you get started.

For example, instead of:

```
sum_updates_j_k = comm.bcast(sum_updates_j_k, root=0)
```

you would use:

```
comm.Bcast(sum_updates_j_k, root=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a case it is useful to have a function that can send `numpy` arrays in parts, e.g.:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import math, numpy
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
def bcast_array_obj(obj = None, dtype = numpy.float64, root = 0):
    """Function for broadcasting of a numpy array object"""
    reporter = 0 if root > 0 else 1
    if rank == root:
        for exp in range(11):
            parts = pow(2, exp)
            err = False
            part_len = math.ceil(len(obj) / parts)
            for part in range(parts):
                part_begin = part * part_len
                part_end = min((part + 1) * part_len, len(obj))
                try:
                    comm.bcast(obj[part_begin: part_end], root = root)
                except:
                    err = True
                err *= comm.recv(source = reporter, tag = 2)
                if err:
                    break
            if err:
                continue
            comm.bcast(None, root = root)
            print('The array was successfully sent in {} part{}'.\
                  format(parts, 's' if parts > 1 else ''))
            return
        sys.stderr.write('Failed to send the array even in 1024 parts')
        sys.stderr.flush()
    else:
        obj = numpy.zeros(0, dtype = dtype)
        while True:
            err = False
            try:
                part_obj = comm.bcast(root = root)
            except:
                err = True
                obj = numpy.zeros(0, dtype = dtype)
            if rank == reporter:
                comm.send(err, dest = root, tag = 2)
            if err:
                continue
            if type(part_obj) != type(None):
                frags = len(obj)
                obj.resize(frags + len(part_obj))
                obj[frags: ] = part_obj
            else:
                break
        return obj
```

This function automatically determines optimal number of parts to break the input array.

For example,

```
if rank != 0:
    z = bcast_array_obj(root = 0)
else:
    z = numpy.zeros(1000000000, dtype = numpy.float64)
    bcast_array_obj(z, root = 0)
```

outputs

```
The array was successfully sent in 4 parts
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an issue in MPI itself and not in MPI4py.  The actual variable which holds the size of the data being communicated is a signed 32 bit integer which will overflow to a negative value for around 2GB of data.

[Maximum amount of data that can be sent using MPI::Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558861/maximum-amount-of-data-that-can-be-sent-using-mpisend)

It's been raised as an issue with MPI4py previously as well [here](https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/23).