# Suggested max size for stack allocations

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

Assuming a need of a buffer with *fixed size*, is there a size limit or threshold, such that under that size limit it's OK to use a fast stack-allocated `std::array`, and above that limit it's better to use a `std::vector` with memory allocated dynamically from the heap (since stack memory is precious and shouldn't be consumed much)?

```
// I think allocating 32 bytes on the stack is just fine.
std::array<BYTE, 32> smallBuffer;

// For 32KB, it's better getting memory from the heap.
std::vector<BYTE> bigBuffer(32*1024);

// Is it better to allocate a 1KB buffer on the stack (with std::array)
// or is it too much, and it's better to allocate on the heap (using std::vector)?
// What about 512 bytes? And 4KB?
// Is there a suggested size threshold?
std::array<BYTE, 1024> buffer;
```

Comment: There were already similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program

Comment: If your system provides you with 8 MiB of stack (default on Mac OS X; Linux will be similar), then you should probably start worrying at somewhere around the 1 MiB size.  With a smaller stack size, worry sooner.

Comment: That's weird.. I always see stack allocations of `char[256]`, `char[512]`, `char[1024]` and sometimes `char[2048]` or `char[4096]` on MSDN.. `4096` is actually fairly common on MSDN's socket and pipe tutorials/docs. It's always something like: `#define BUFSIZE 4096`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Depends on how much stack other functions in the call stack might have already / will consume at the same time, especially recursive functions. Better err on the conservative side, it's less painful.

Comment: I managed to link the same question twice, but I wished to have this for the second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c

Comment: Indeed, 4096 is pretty common, so 1 MiB looks quite unreasonable.

Comment: It is *implementation specific*

Answer (score 5):

There is no official limit. You could grow or reduce the default stack size on every system.
The default warning on stack size is **16 Kb** for Visual Studio user mode application and **1 Kb** in kernel mode. Some static analyser tools use the same limit for warning.

> ```
> warning C6262: Function uses '30000' bytes of stack: exceeds /analyze:stacksize'16384'. Consider moving some data to heap
> ```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6262
It's only a warning, but it could be considered as a recommended stack allocation limit.