# What is the maximum index for c++ new[] operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I thought that the maximum index for an array is a signed int, 2147483647. However reading online, I found posts stating that for a 32 bit system an array can have 4294967295 elements, unsigned int. And for a 64 bit system, an array can have 2^64 elements, 18446744073709551616.

When I tried to compile and run the following program, I got a warning:

> [Warning] integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int maxindex = 2147483647+1;

   char* p = new char [maxindex];

   for(int i = 0; i < maxindex; i++)
   {
       p[i] = 65;   
   }

   cout<<"Value at index "<<maxindex-1<<" is "<<p[maxindex-1]<<endl;

   delete[] p;

   return 0;
}
```

When I ran the program, it terminated immediately:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>     what():  std::bad_alloc
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

If I change `int maxindex = 2147483647+1;` to `int maxindex = 2147483647;` the program runs with no problems. What am I doing wrong and is the limit for new[] index 2^64, 18446744073709551616, or 2147483647?

Comment: because int on your platform can only hold 32 bits(4 bytes), so that 2147483647+1 equals to -2147483648, and new probably doesnt like negative sizes. use long long, or unsigned int if you want higher than 2147483647

Comment: "What is the maximum index for c++ new[] operator?" – it depends on your architecture, and the available free memory. Also, it's not an index, it's a size.

Comment: You should get used to unsigned integers (size_t), too

Comment: "When I tried to compile and run the following program, I got a warning". You need to understand the warning and fix it, rather than proceed with running your program and wonder why it gives you somewhat unexpected results.

Comment: I changed int maxindex = 2147483647+1; to  unsigned int maxindex = 2147483647+1; Now it runs but I'm still getting the warning!  

    [Warning] integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a max array length limit in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c)

Comment: size of a type is `size_t`, not `unsigned int`

Comment: You're asking about the maximum *size*, not the maximum *index*.

Comment: Got it! Needed to append a u after the numbers unsigned int maxindex = 2147483647u+1u; No warnings now

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, the maximum size an array can have is of type [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). So you should be using `size_t` variables when you are declaring arrays and iterating over them.

> std::size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible
>   object of any type (including array) [...] std::size_t can safely store the value of any non-member pointer [...]
>   When indexing C++ containers, such as std::string, std::vector, etc, the appropriate type is the member typedef size_type provided by such containers. It is usually defined as a synonym for std::size_t.

Then, the amount of virtual memory available to your process dictates how much memory you are allowed to allocate on the heap (using the `new` operator), and on the stack using static arrays.

The exception you get, `std::bad_alloc`, is thrown by the standard definitions of operator `new` and operator `new[]` when they fail to allocate the requested storage space, typically because there is not enough virtual memory available.