# Crash on big array in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on OpenCL and I code like this in MS VS 2012:

```
cl_float test[480000];
```

It can be complied successfully but the program crashes when it enter the function which the codes above are in. Error Code: 0xC000041D.

It is interrupted near the end of file "chkstk.asm":

```
; Find next lower page and probe
cs20:
        sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
        test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.
        jmp     short cs10

_chkstk endp

        end
```

On the line `test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.`.

I don't think this array is too big to be allocated.

---

So next, I want to try another way:

```
cl_float4 *PixVectIn=(cl_float4*)malloc(480000*sizeof(cl_float4));
for(unsigned int a=0;a<800;a++){
    for(unsigned int b=0;b<600;b++){
        PixVectIn[a*800+b].x=PixVect[a][b][0];
        PixVectIn[a*800+b].y=PixVect[a][b][1];
        PixVectIn[a*800+b].z=PixVect[a][b][2];
    }
}
```

The program also can be built. This time, it crashes when run the "for" loop.

It stop at `PixVectIn[a*800+b].x=PixVect[a][b][0];`. It shows me the same error code and at this moment, a=600 and b=252. Looks like it reaches a boundary something.

I'm not sure. It may because I changed certain options in project properties.

Comment: For the first, 1MB is a typical stack size limit, and the array is larger than that. For the second, 600*800 + 252 is greater than 480000.

Comment: [Is there a max array length limit in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/216731/14065)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should compare the pointer `malloc` returned with `NULL`, otherwise you don't know if the allocation was successful.

Second your indices are wrong: `PixVectIn[a*800+b]` will go out of the bounds of 480000, since your `a` alone goes up to 800, and 800^2 is > 480000. Maybe you meant `a*b`?

Comment: Probably meant a*600+b.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I made a simple mistake. This is stupid... I want to do `PixVectIn[b*800+a]`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Increase your stack size or declare that array as static or place it in global scope. Your stack (in your case) is not big enough to handle 1920000 bytes...

Comment: Even better, the array should be a (dynamically allocated) heap data. For example, by using `std::vector`

Comment: @Basile: Your suggestion is good. I do not know if OpenCL can work with std:vector or similar. Any info ?

Comment: Read more about C++11 [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).  You can use its `data` member function to get a pointer. You might want to upgrade your compiler to something C++11 compliant

Answer (score 1):

First program is bitten by *stack overflow*.

For the second, `a*800+b` is access violation for values like 799, `800*800 + 600 > 480000`.

Also better replace this:

```
cl_float4 *PixVectIn=(cl_float4*)malloc(480000*sizeof(cl_float4));
```

with this:

```
std::vector<cl_float4> PixVectIn(480000);
```