# Maximum number of elements in a 2D integer array

Tags: c, memory, multidimensional-array

Is there any limit as to how many elements a `2D integer array` can contain in `C`?
PS : I was expecting there would be some space limitations in declaring an array but could not find any such reference in the internet.

Comment: The array cannot exceed `SIZE_MAX` bytes (this constant is defined in `limits.h`).  Particular systems might have smaller limits depending on how much memory is available.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c

Comment: @RishikeshRaje that's a C++ question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your `RAM` or the memory available for you.

`i:e:` My program used to crash when I declared a global array `a[100000][10000]`, but this declaration is fine with the system now I have.

Comment: This isn't really true. For example, on 32 bit Windows you couldn't allocate more than 4,29Gb even if your computer had more RAM than that. Anyway, C provides the `size_t` type as a way to find out how much memory you can allocate in one object.

Comment: @Lundin : Thanks for clearing my misconception. I think i got it now.

Answer (score -1):

The `size_t` type is defined to be large enough to contain the size of any object in the program, including arrays. So the largest possible array size can be described as `2^(8*sizeof(size_t)` bytes.

For convenience, this value can be obtained through the `SIZE_MAX` constant in limits.h. It is guaranteed to be at least 65535 but is realistically a larger value, most likely 2^32 on 32 bit systems and 2^64 on 64 bit systems.

Answer (score -1):

Maximum imposed by the C/C++ standard: `x * y * z <= SIZE_MAX`, where SIZE_MAX is implementation defined, x is one dimension of the array, y is the other dimension, and z is the size of the element in bytes. e.g. `element_t A[x][y]`, `z = sizeof(element_t)`.