# C++ - Float array not storing values after a certain very large index

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, opengl-3

In my program, I'm creating terrain using Perlin noise. The terrain is being generated correctly and now I'm trying to store my calculated normals into a float array called *normals*. It's storing the normals correctly up to a certain index but then it just stores 0s. Here is my code:

```
float frequency = 8;
float flagVertices[ N*N*VALS_PER_VERT*VERTICES_PER_QUAD ];
float normals[ N*N*VALS_PER_VERT*VERTICES_PER_QUAD ];
int idxFlag = 0;
int normFlag = 0;
for (int i=0;i < N;i++){
    for (int j=0;j < N;j++){
        // *** Face 1 ***
        // (0,0)
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)i/N;
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = 0.2f*PerlinNoise( glm::vec2( (float)i/N*frequency, (float)j/N*frequency ) );
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)j/N;
        glm::vec3 p0 = glm::vec3(flagVertices[idxFlag-3], flagVertices[idxFlag-2], flagVertices[idxFlag-1]);                

        // (0,1)
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)i/N;
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = 0.2f*PerlinNoise( glm::vec2( (float)i/N*frequency, (float)(j+1)/N*frequency ) );
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)(j+1)/N; 
        glm::vec3 p1 = glm::vec3(flagVertices[idxFlag-3], flagVertices[idxFlag-2], flagVertices[idxFlag-1]); 

        // (1,1)
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)(i+1)/N;
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = 0.2f*PerlinNoise( glm::vec2( (float)(i+1)/N*frequency, (float)(j+1)/N*frequency ) );
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)(j+1)/N; 
        glm::vec3 p2 = glm::vec3(flagVertices[idxFlag-3], flagVertices[idxFlag-2], flagVertices[idxFlag-1]);

        // Adding in normals
        glm::vec3 normal = glm::abs(glm::triangleNormal(p0,p1,p2));
        normals[normFlag++] = normal.x;
        normals[normFlag++] = normal.y;
        normals[normFlag++] = normal.z;

        // *** Face 2 ***
        // (1,1)
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)(i+1)/N;
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = 0.2f*PerlinNoise( glm::vec2( (float)(i+1)/N*frequency, (float)(j+1)/N*frequency ) );
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)(j+1)/N;
        glm::vec3 p3 = glm::vec3(flagVertices[idxFlag-3], flagVertices[idxFlag-2], flagVertices[idxFlag-1]); 

        // (1,0)
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)(i+1)/N;
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = 0.2f*PerlinNoise( glm::vec2( (float)(i+1)/N*frequency, (float)j/N*frequency ) );
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)j/N;
        glm::vec3 p4 = glm::vec3(flagVertices[idxFlag-3], flagVertices[idxFlag-2], flagVertices[idxFlag-1]); 

        // (0,0)
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)i/N;
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = 0.2f*PerlinNoise( glm::vec2( (float)i/N*frequency, (float)j/N*frequency ) );
        flagVertices[idxFlag++] = (float)j/N;
        glm::vec3 p5 = glm::vec3(flagVertices[idxFlag-3], flagVertices[idxFlag-2], flagVertices[idxFlag-1]);

        // Adding in normals
        normal = glm::abs(glm::triangleNormal(p3,p4,p5));
        normals[normFlag++] = normal.x;
        normals[normFlag++] = normal.y;
        normals[normFlag++] = normal.z;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that this is a C++ problem, I'm having, because I've tried printing out the normals just after it's been created and I see no 0s. But when I'm printing out the normals from the array (with the right index), I just get a 0.

Comment: What is `N`? What is `VALS_PER_VERT`? What is `VERTICES_PER_QUAD`? Are you sure your indexing will never be out of bounds? Try using a memory debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or similar.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216731/410767) on array size limitations insightful.  More generally, older compilers may have limitations well below what the memory architecture supports.  It's probably best to allocate large memory blocks dynamically.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Surely if that was kicking in then the OP would be getting an exception.  Still, putting large arrays on the stack is certainly poor practise.  They should be dynamically allocated instead.

Comment: N, VALS_PER_VERT and VERTICES_PER_QUAD are just macro numbers, I've defined, that are used for generating the terrain.

Comment: I haven't tried allocating memory to the heap yet, I'll give that a shot in a bit.

Comment: But what are their definitions? What values will be used in your arrays? Better yet, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: N=64, VALS_PER_VERT=3, VERTICES_PER_QUAD=6. I can't create that sort of example to replicate the actual error because it requires a lot of code.

Comment: Making the arrays dynamic still produces the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `normals` array, drop the multiplication with `VALS_PER_VERT`. It will make your array three times bigger than it needs to be.

The values of the elements that you don't initialize depends on where you define the arrays: If they are defined as global (or namespace) variables they will be initialized as zero; If they are defined as local variables inside a function their values will be *indeterminate* (and reading them will lead to *undefined behavior*).

So definition should be

```
float normals[ N*N*VERTICES_PER_QUAD ];
```

and remember to not go out of bounds of it. This will make all elements initialized inside the loop you show.

Comment: I see, that explains as to why there are 0s in the array.

Edit: Your answer made me realise that I needed to store the normals 4 additional times per loop. Thank you!