# A C++ Program which works fine in online compilers and linux operating systems, but not on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, memory

While compiling a problem:
[Geeks For Geeks: First Repeating Element](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/first-repeating-element4018/1//) on a Windows operating system I noticed that I was not getting any output for my solution. But when I compiled the same code on a Linux operating system and on online compilers, it worked absolutely fine without producing any errors.

Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];

    for(int i=0; i <n; i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    int size= 1e6+1; // WA on windows
    int A[size];
    int min_index=INT_MAX;

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        A[i]=-1;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(A[arr[i]]!=-1)
            min_index=min(min_index, A[arr[i]]);
        else
            A[arr[i]]=i;
    }

    if(min_index==INT_MAX) 
        cout<<"-1";
    else
        cout<< min_index+1;

    return 0;
}
```

Sample Test Case:

```
7
1 5 3 4 3 5 6
```

Expected output:

```
2
```

Output on Windows:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6cA9.png)

Output on Linux:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt2NA.png)

Explanation for the program from line 14 of code:

I created an array `A` of size `1e6+1` to store value `i` on its `arr[i]`th index.
Array `A` was earlier initialized with value `-1`. It runs for `n` number of times and variable `min_index` stores the index of the least repeating number from the array `arr`.
After initializing smaller values of array `int size = 10` and using very small test cases(also max value of arr[i] is lesser than size of `A`; I realize that the program runs perfectly in Windows.

As far as I understand, Windows might be having some trouble intializing arrays of such large length (Please correct me if I'm wrong). But why isn't it the same in the case of Linux?

Comment: To begin with: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) To continue: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) And while `using namespace std;` is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) it's often considered okay for small and simple examples.

Comment: And to finish: Don't use so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites as any kind of teaching or learning resources. They are *not* that, and could be actively harmful for your proper learning. Get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and take classes to learn C++ (and programming in general) properly.

Comment: And I'm actually surprised that the program even run on Windows, considering that your VLA (Variable-Length Array) `A` is four million bytes large. The default stack-size (and local variables are usually stored on the stack) on Windows is only a single MiB. Also `1e+1` is a *floating point* value (of type `double`) and not more readable than `1000001`.

Comment: Or perhaps the problem is that the VLA `A` really is too large and your program *crashes*? That means you need to learn something else not taught by such sites: ***Debugging***.

Comment: `int A[size];` No.  The following is proper C++ code: `std::vector<int> A(size);`.  Second, as already mentioned, use a C++ book to learn C++.  If you had done that, you would not have made the mistake, since no good C++ book shows declaring arrays using a runtime variable.

Comment: The problem could be: `int A[1e6+1]` that is a large array. Checkout this: [Is there a max array length limit in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216731/14065). A simple solution may be to change that to a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard C++, hence you should not expect it to be portable.

`int arr[n];` is not standard C++. Some compilers offer variable length arrays as extension, but it isnt portable. Same goes for `int A[size];`.

Sadly most of the C++ code presented on that site is not proper C++ code but some dialect.

For more details see: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4117728) and [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). That Q&As should also explain the standard portable alternatives.